# How can I change the indentation in quote and quotation environments and commands?

Tags: indentation, lengths, quoting

I need to change the indentation that the `quote` and `quotation` environments and commands employ. I assume that there is some length I need to set, but I've googled around, and cannot find what I am after. So, how to alter the indentation?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

What about something like that ?

```
\newenvironment{myquote}%
  {\list{}{\leftmargin=0.3in\rightmargin=0.3in}\item[]}%
  {\endlist}
```

You can also make the margin size an option:

```
\newenvironment{myquote}[1]%
  {\list{}{\leftmargin=#1\rightmargin=#1}\item[]}%
  {\endlist}
```

And use with:

```
\begin{myquote}{0.3in}
  % ...
\end{myquote}
```

Comment: That works, but modifying the original quote environments seems better; with this, I will have to do a global replace of `myquote` with `quote` to return to a fully standard document, whereas by modifying the environment itself, commenting out the modification would suffice. Still, +1 and an acceptance in the future if nothing like what I'd envisioned is forthcoming.

Comment: Can't you use \renewenvironment{quote} with the code above instead?

Comment: @frabjous: Well, *now* that you say that, it is obvious. :-)

Answer (score 25):

Use the [`etoolbox`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/etoolbox.html) package to patch the `\quote` command.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\quote}{\rightmargin}{\leftmargin 4em \rightmargin}{}{}
```

(The default definition of `\quote` is `\list{}{\rightmargin\leftmargin}\item\relax`.)

Comment: What's the advantage of using `etoolbox` over just a `\renewenvironment`?

Comment: @doncherry: Selectively changing a definition instead of copy-paste-change may have two advantages: a) Updates of other parts of the definition carry over to your change (but should be monitored) b) If the original definition is long, you may save a lot of writing with a concise partial change.

Comment: For the sake of learning by doing, I want to patch the `\quote` and `\quotation` commands with `\color{blue}` or similar, as found in @igor-kotelnikov's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/72756/8272): `\newenvironment{myquotation}{\setlength{\leftmargini}{0em}\color{blue}\quotation}{\endquotation}`.

Comment: Finally, I've used `\apptocmd{\quote}{\color{blue}}{}{}`. Hope this is the right way to it in this case, instead of `patchcmd`.

Answer (score 18):

I recently released the [`quoting`](http://ctan.org/pkg/quoting) package which provides a consolidated environment for displayed text as an alternative to `quotation` and `quote`. As the main feature, *"[f]irst-line indentation is activated by adding a blank line before the `quoting` environment"*. With regard to the question at hand: It is also possible to change left-hand and right-hand indentation globally or for single environments using a key--value syntax.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[leftmargin=3em]{quoting}

\begin{document}

\blindtext
% Removing the comment sign in the following line will activate first-line indentation
%
\begin{quoting}
\blindtext
\end{quoting}

\blindtext
%
\begin{quoting}[leftmargin=\parindent]
\blindtext
\end{quoting}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I realised this whole time that I imported the quoting environment but was using quotation instead of quote in my tex.

Answer (score 4):

`\advance\leftmargini 2em` before `\begin{quote}` or `\begin{quotation}`.

Comment: Works, but affects all list-like environments.

Comment: I haven't tried this, but if you enclose the entire thing in a \begingroup and \endgroup then it should localize the effect.

Answer (score 2):

I would modify fredz's answer a bit:

```
\newenvironment{myquotation}{\setlength{\leftmargini}{0em}\quotation}{\endquotation}
```

This preserves identation in the beginning of paragraphs. For my own needs I have

```
\newenvironment{myquotation}{\setlength{\leftmargini}{0em}\color{blue}\quotation}{\endquotation}
```

to print long quotations in blue color.