# Insert quotations

Tags: environments, quoting

I would like to insert some literature quotations in my thesis. My first thought was to modify the verse environment as demonstrated in [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2396/how-can-i-change-the-indentation-in-quote-and-quotation-environments-and-commands), though the result is not so pleasing.

I would like each quotation to be in quotation marks, provide an easy way to attribute the source below the quotation and be right aligned.

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but check the epigraph package. This should work with report.

Comment: Sorry for the Greek text, but you can get the feeling. I am referring to the text which is aligned to the right or something like that. http://thesis.ekt.gr/thesisBookReader/id/1668#page/22/mode/2up

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you’re using the KOMA-Script document classes, take a look at the `\dictum` command in the documentation – this does exactly what you want.

For example, to put a quotation in front of a chapter:

```
\setchapterpreamble{
  \dictum[Anonymous]{Forecasting is the art of saying what is going to happen
    and then to explain why it didn’t.}}

\chapter{Weather forecasting}
```

Comment: \documentclass[12pt,twoside,openright]{report} is my document class. Could I use it in any way (inclusion of a package perhaps? ) without changing the layout of my document?

Comment: Load the `scrextend` package - it is part of KOMA-script and also provides the `\dictum` command.

Comment: @myle: if you’re using the standard classes, I *strongly suggest* that you switch to the KOMA classes instead: each of the standard classes has a direct equivalent in the KOMA classes – the one for `report` is `scrreprt`. Granted, the layout will *not* be preserved but changing the layout to anything you like is really easy once you’ve read the (quite short) introduction on layouting in the KOMA documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot Konrad! I replaced `report` with `scrreprt` and my document compiled without any problem and only slight differences in the layout. The `\setchapterpreamble` worked as advertised though some googling showed up its equivalent for the standard classes the [epigraph](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=epigraph).