# Linebreaking in a correct manner

Tags: line-breaking, typography, warnings

So this might be a really basic question, but I couldn't find anything about it.

In my amateur style of LaTeX typesetting, I sometimes want linebreaks in random places for various reasons. I usually end up using `\\\\`, which gives an underfull warning but compiles fine.

I'm getting to the point of using LaTeX often enough that it's worth wondering:

- Why is this not recommended by the compiler?
- What should I do instead?

Examples

```
This is a paragraph where I write some stuff
\\\\
This is a paragraph which I might want to clearly delimit. 
I guess I have a hard time coming up with an example, since
a quotation or a pancake recipe would probably be better
off contained in its own figure.

\begin{lemma} (Impossibility of nice typecasting lemma)
Let A be some arbitrary typecasting rule. Assume mathematician B wants to ignore it.
\\\\
Then maybe I want to separate the assumptions and the conclusion of the lemma very clearly.
```

This seems to be a typical "it's doable, but why would you want to?" question. In general I think indentation after an empty line almost always looks kind of weird. Maybe typography isn't the place for being a maverick, so if I'm breaking general guidelines here it would be nice to know I guess.

Comment: I'm really curious: Where did you get the idea to use `\\\\ `? None of the manuals I know recommend that.

Comment: Well two slashes is one line break, so why not? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume by 'rowbreak' you mean 'linebreak'. If not, disregard my answer. I think perhaps \\ is what you want instead of \\\\. Unless you want two line breaks, in which case you could just skip a line like so, to get a new paragraph:

```
Text of a new paragraph.

\noindent Text of the rest of the paragraph, with a gap of one line between the two.
```

If I've misunderstood your question could you provide an example of what you're trying to achieve and how you're trying to code it up?

Comment: Yeah I meant linebreak, sorry. But your method produces indentation in the second paragraph, which is what I sometimes want to avoid.

Comment: Use \noindent at the start of the paragraph, and that should avoid the issue.

Comment: No worries! Glad it's working now. :)

Comment: @BenjaminLindqvist Why shouldn't a new paragraph be indented?

Comment: @egreg I can probably think of many examples, will update the question

Comment: @BenjaminLindqvist I can think to none, to be honest, *particularly* if you want a big break between the two paragraphs.

Answer (score 3):

Add the [`parskip package`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40429/how-to-use-the-parskip-package-space-in-between-paragraphs) to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{parskip}
```

You can leave the `////` from your example and use a white space instead

Optionally you can set the distances

```
% Set distance between paragraphs (absolute distance and "rubber")
\setlength{\parskip}{0.4cm plus2mm minus2mm}
% No indent,
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
```