# What does the phrase "Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph" actually mean?

Tags: errors, tex-core, boxes, paragraphs, underfull

What does the actual phrase above mean?

Comment: Package `parskip` can resolve most of such warnings, you can refer to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40432/85946) for more details.

Answer (score 106):

99 times out of 100 it means you have `\\` incorrectly placed at the end of a paragraph.  But to dissect the message:

> Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 4--5

A box is underfull if there is not enough content to fill its stated size.

If you go `\hbox to 5cm{A}` then it makes a horizontal box (`\hbox`) 5cm wide just containing an A so it is underfull and will generate a warning, the exact amount of badness depends how much any white space is over-stretched, but here there is no white space so it is infinitely bad, which is arbitrarily truncated to the maximum value, 10000.

By placing `\\` at the end of a paragraph you force a line break but there is nothing at all in the forced final line of the paragraph so it is a box that is `\textwidth` wide with no content. It appears a bit like vertical space but it is not it is a spurious line at the end of the paragraph. So for example it does not stretch and is not dropped at the start of a page.

Comment: @gernot oh I was out by a factor of 10, thanks:-)

Comment: Thank you for that well and clearly explained answer to my question.

Comment: @CharlesBoehm Can you please explain [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511441/newline-after-hbox-underfull-hbox-badness-10000-in-paragraph) to me ?

Comment: What if I write \\ , put a blank line and then write something?. In this scenario, there is something written after \\, but I am still getting this error!

Comment: @sreerajt that is exactly the case described here: it is always wrong to have a blank line after `\\ `

Comment: what box? is a paragraph a box? I didn't start any hbox, but I have this message

Comment: every line of a paragraph is a box and `\\ ` at the end of a paragraph forces a spurious empty line

Comment: I don't have any `\\` at the end but still get the warning. It looks like the text is too long for being put on one line, but why doesn't it just get split without any warnings?...

Comment: @ka3ak don't ask new questions as comments on old posts, ask a new question referencing this one. It is anyway impossible to answer without seeing the example code, there are many reasons why the line may or may not break at a particular place.

Comment: Then when should I use \\? I "misused" it but it still typesets with no problem (except this message appears in the console)

Comment: It is making an empy white line of text so if a page break happens you will get a blank line at the of the page, it is not vertical space it is a line of text with no text. You should (almost) only ever use `\\ ` in alignment constructs like `tabular` or `align`. You vary rarely need to use it mid-paragraph to force a line break but never use it at the end of a paragraph. It does not "typeset with no problem" it makes essentially broken output and tex warns you about it with good reason. @user71207

Comment: Just a snippet of a comment. There are many reasons why underfull errors may occur, as mentioned here and ways to address them, but the overriding reason for me has been in paragraph construction, namely the writing. I found that while many overfull errors could be eliminated globally by using one command or another, fixing underfull errors in long documents was best accomplished during the editing phase. Consequently, I think of underfull errors, not as technical hurdles, but one offering an opportunity to create a more coherent and communicable presentation.

Comment: @afrothetics underfull boxes due to difficult line breaking are an oportunity to rewrite as you suggest but they are not normally 10000, underfull 10000 is almost always as described here, which is essentially a syntax error which is unfortunately just presented as a warning.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Would be good to have an alternative/solution, [see comment in question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334246/what-does-the-phrase-underfull-hbox-badness-10000-in-paragraph-actually-mea#comment1501353_334246)

Comment: @user3123159 ? the comment leads to an answer which basically says the same, to remove this warning remove the `\\ ` (that answer  is also about `\parskip` but that is not really related to this question. Misplaced `\\ `give the warning here whether or not `parskip` is used.

Comment: once I got the warning with the 2 backslashes, but then the warning disappeared without intervention.

Comment: @user3123159 warnings never disappear without intervention. If the warning changed, the code changed somewhere

Answer (score -5):

I just find out that using new line command `\\` in latex (overleaf) causes the problem.

If you end a line with `\\` and start with a nonempty line then it works fine.

Example:

```
\begin{document}
Hello this is the first line.\\
This is the second line.\\ 
\end{document}
```

But when I need to skip one line (like pressing enter twice) I must use `\\ \\` (i.e. \\ twice). Since we are putting \\ at the end of an empty line this causes the problem.

Example:

```
\begin{document} 
Hello this is the first line.\\
\\ %This is an empty line
This is the third line.
\end{document}
```

**Solution:**
Use a text in white color between `\\` and `\\` to resolve this, though xcolor package will be required for this. Here is the code.

```
\begin{article}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
Hello this is the first line.\\
{\color{white}-}\\ % This line will now show in pdf and no error will be generated.
This is the third line.
\end{article}
```

Hope this works!

Comment: Please use neither `\\ ` nor`\\ \\ ` to make a vertical distance. If you want paragraph skip instead of paragraph indent, configure paragraphs, e.g., using package `parskip` and use either an empty line in the source code or `\par`. If you want a vertical distance for another reason use a vertical distance command like `\bigskip` or `\vspace{…}` between paragraphs. If you want a vertical distance in a special environment like a `tabular` use the optional argument of `\\[…]`. See also David's answer and the comments to it for more information.

Comment: Thanks! Can you provide a sample code for that? I am also not fully satisfied with my answer (I was using this because it was working). I am not very fluent in latex so a code would be really great.

Comment: For what do you want an example? For using parskip? → https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40429/how-to-use-the-parskip-package-space-in-between-paragraphs and many other questions about parskip etc. If you need more help, you should ask a question wit a real [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) and a concrete question. BTW: Your shown code does usually not work, because `article` is not an environment but a class and text requires `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`. You really should delete the answer or improve it.

Comment: The answers to this question [When to use `\par` and when ``\\``](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82664) should tell you why using `\\ ` isn't a good idea.

Comment: Thanks to both barbarabeeton and cabohah for the suggestions.

Comment: sorry this answer is completely wrong, users should never use `\\ ` in this way.