# Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) warning, but the output is correct

Tags: equations

I'm trying to add an equation to my paper and the result is as I want. However, I get the warning:

> Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 4--12

What does it mean and how can I get rid of it?

Here is the code:

```
(time)=$\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{i} U_i*t_i}{U_top}$ \newline
\newline
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\newline` command creates this warning because it finds an end of line caused by something external of the line break internal rules. Generally (depending on your code and the wanted output) using `\newline` is not recommended except of special cases and if possible you should prefer a `\vspace{\baselineskip}` or a `\linebreak` or not-inline math etc. But This warning is nothing to worry about if you wish to have a new line at this specific place and you may ignore that. It is not an error.

Comment: never use two consecutive `\newline` or a `\newline` at the end of a paragraph.

Comment: possible duplicate https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334246/what-does-the-phrase-underfull-hbox-badness-10000-in-paragraph-actually-mea/334249#334249

Comment: This is a guess: you want an unnumbered display equation.  For that, a better formulation is
 `\[\textrm{time} = \frac{\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{i} U_i*t_i}{U_top}\]`

Comment: unrelated but you have the `=` outside of math so will get the wrong spacing, and  I would mark that as `\[(\mathrm{time})=\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{i} U_i*t_i}{U_{\mathrm{top}}\]`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- no `\\ ` here.

Comment: @koleygr I would worry about it if it were my document, I don't think it is good to advise this error can be ignored, the spurious line that it is warning about has very bad behaviour at a page break for example.

Comment: @barbarabeeton `\\ ` and `\newline` are the same thing.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle .. I am talking general and this is a warning ... Had in mind something like `\noindent {\bfseries Question 1:}\newline This is the body of the question` that I suppose this same warning is ok... Added some solutions too and suggested to avoid it for this case.

Comment: @koleygr there would not be a warning from such a use.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ... just tested and show that ... I didn't knew that. Thanks

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- But that's not obvious, requires digging.  (I'm standing up here for newbies and forgetful senior citizens.)

Comment: Yes that's why I linked to a question about the message not one asking about `\\ `