# Underfull and overfull in minipage environment

Tags: itemize, minipage, includegraphics

I get very often, warnings about the space used in minipage environment such as:

Overfull \hbox (2.61108pt too wide)

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph

I tried many times to optimize the spaces in the paragraphs and pictures, but warnings still showing up in the message window. Here is an example of my report

```
   \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\subsubsection*{Essai Equivalent de Sable}
Au cours d mon stage, on a fait 2 fois cet essai. Il consiste à déterminer la qualité du sable qu'on utilse dans la construction des chaussés et batiments .Les étapes de cet essai sont comme suite:
\begin{enumerate}
\item On  ramène une éprouvette graduée de 41 cm.
\item On prépare 5 litres de solution lavante en diluant une dose de liquide concentré de marque 'EUROMATEST' sur 5 litre d'eau.
\item On remplie l'éprouvette avec 120 grammes de sable à l'aide d'un entonnoir, et on prépare de meme façon la deuxième éprouvette.
\item On laisse les deux éprouvettes au repos pendant 10 minutes.
\item On ferme les deux éprouvettes avec leurs bouchons, et On les agite 90 fois.
\item On enlève les bouchons et on remplie avec l'eau jusqu'au deuxième trait en lavant les parois intérieurs afin de récupérer toute les impuretés du sable.
\item On laisse les deux éprouvette au repos pendant 20 minutes.
\item On abaisse le piston dans le liquide pour séparer le floculat de l'eau.
\item on lit les hauteurs H1 et H2.
\item On calcule l'équivalent de sable à l'aide de la formule suivante $ES= \frac{H1}{H2} \times 100 $. 
\end{enumerate}
 \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
 \begin{center}
 \includegraphics[width=7cm , height=5cm]{../LABO MEZAAD/IMG_20200716_112034_1.jpg} 
\captionof{figure}{Liquide Concentré.}
 \end{center}
 \end{minipage}
 \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth} 
 \begin{center}
 \includegraphics[width=7cm , height=5cm]{../1200px-Equivalent-de-sable-2.svg.png} 
\captionof{figure}{Les Normes de ES}
 \end{center}
 \end{minipage}
\subsubsection*{Essai Cisaillement à la boite}
On a fait cet essai après chaque prélèvement de l'échantillon à l'aide d 'une sondeuse. Il est important pour identifier les caractéristiques géotechniques du sol. Il est nécessaire pour avoir le comportement du sol de aux séismes et connaitre le dimensionnement de la fondation. Les étapes effectuées dans cet essai sont comme suite :
Il existe deux types d'essai cisaillement : Cisaillement drainé, Cisaillement non-drainé. Dans Laboratoire, on a fait seulement l'essai non-drainé.
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{enumerate}
\item On place sur le fond de la boite inférieur, une plaque pleine,puis une plaque perforés.
\item On place sur ces plaques,l'échantillon du sol.
\item  On place de meme façon les deux plaques(pleines et perforés) sur l'échantillon.
\item On vice la boite supérieur avec la boite inférieur.
\item On place le Piston.
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=7cm , height=5cm]{../LABO MEZAAD/IMG_20200701_151254.jpg} 
\captionof{figure}{Les boites de Casagrande}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
```

If you have any suggestions or advices, please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: the underfull 10000 message is usually this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334246/what-does-the-phrase-underfull-hbox-badness-10000-in-paragraph-actually-mea/334249#334249

Comment: Unrelated but don't use both `width= , height=` this may distort the image, just  use one or the other, so both directions scale by the same amount.

Comment: It would have been helpful if you'd pasted the entire box message.  The line number is useful.

Answer (score 2):

You need `\noindent` before and `%` between the minpages and, of course, use
`width=\linewidth` for the images to be sure that the image fits the minipage width:

```
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=5cm]{../LABO MEZAAD/IMG_20200716_112034_1.jpg} 
\captionof{figure}{Liquide Concentré.}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth} 
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=5cm]{../1200px-Equivalent-de-sable-2.svg.png} 
\captionof{figure}{Les Normes de ES}
\end{minipage}
```

The second pair of minipages should be smaller than `0.5\textwidth` to get a margin between the list and the image.

The complete document with option `draft`, which marks all overfull boxes. Can be deleted later.
By the way: Why do you choose the old OT1 encoding?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,draft]{report}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

\subsubsection*{Essai Equivalent de Sable}
Au cours d mon stage, on a fait 2 fois cet essai. Il consiste à déterminer la qualité du sable 
qu'on utilse dans la construction des chaussés et batiments .Les étapes de cet essai sont comme 
suite:
\begin{enumerate}
\item On  ramène une éprouvette graduée de 41 cm.
\item On prépare 5 litres de solution lavante en diluant une dose de liquide concentré de marque 
'EUROMATEST' sur 5 litre d'eau.
\item On remplie l'éprouvette avec 120 grammes de sable à l'aide d'un entonnoir, et on prépare de 
meme façon la deuxième éprouvette.
\item On laisse les deux éprouvettes au repos pendant 10 minutes.
\item On ferme les deux éprouvettes avec leurs bouchons, et On les agite 90 fois.
\item On enlève les bouchons et on remplie avec l'eau jusqu'au deuxième trait en lavant les parois 
intérieurs afin de récupérer toute les impuretés du sable.
\item On laisse les deux éprouvette au repos pendant 20 minutes.
\item On abaisse le piston dans le liquide pour séparer le floculat de l'eau.
\item on lit les hauteurs H1 et H2.
\item On calcule l'équivalent de sable à l'aide de la formule suivante $ES= \frac{H1}{H2} \times 
100 $. 
\end{enumerate}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=5cm]{../LABO MEZAAD/IMG_20200716_112034_1.jpg} 
\captionof{figure}{Liquide Concentré.}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth} 
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=5cm]{../1200px-Equivalent-de-sable-2.svg.png} 
\captionof{figure}{Les Normes de ES}
\end{minipage}
 
\subsubsection*{Essai Cisaillement à la boite}

On a fait cet essai après chaque prélèvement de l'échantillon à l'aide d 'une sondeuse. Il est 
important pour identifier les caractéristiques géotechniques du sol. Il est nécessaire pour avoir 
le comportement du sol de aux séismes et connaitre le dimensionnement de la fondation. Les étapes 
effectuées dans cet essai sont comme suite :
Il existe deux types d'essai cisaillement : Cisaillement drainé, Cisaillement non-drainé. Dans 
Laboratoire, on a fait seulement l'essai non-drainé.

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.49\textwidth}
\begin{enumerate}
\item On place sur le fond de la boite inférieur, une plaque pleine,puis une plaque perforés.
\item On place sur ces plaques,l'échantillon du sol.
\item  On place de meme façon les deux plaques(pleines et perforés) sur l'échantillon.
\item On vice la boite supérieur avec la boite inférieur.
\item On place le Piston.
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.49\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=5cm]{../LABO MEZAAD/IMG_20200701_151254.jpg} 
\captionof{figure}{Les boites de Casagrande}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

With use of `tabularx` in `figure` float with positioning option`[!¨h]`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[demo,  % in real document remove this option
            export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\subsubsection*{Essai Equivalent de Sable}
Au cours d mon stage, on a fait 2 fois cet essai. Il consiste à déterminer la qualité du sable qu'on utilse dans la construction des chaussés et batiments .Les étapes de cet essai sont comme suite:
\begin{enumerate}
\item On  ramène une éprouvette graduée de 41 cm.
\item On prépare 5 litres de solution lavante en diluant une dose de liquide concentré de marque 'EUROMATEST' sur 5 litre d'eau.
\item On remplie l'éprouvette avec 120 grammes de sable à l'aide d'un entonnoir, et on prépare de meme façon la deuxième éprouvette.
\item On laisse les deux éprouvettes au repos pendant 10 minutes.
\item On ferme les deux éprouvettes avec leurs bouchons, et On les agite 90 fois.
\item On enlève les bouchons et on remplie avec l'eau jusqu'au deuxième trait en lavant les parois intérieurs afin de récupérer toute les impuretés du sable.
\item On laisse les deux éprouvette au repos pendant 20 minutes.
\item On abaisse le piston dans le liquide pour séparer le floculat de l'eau.
\item on lit les hauteurs H1 et H2.
\item On calcule l'équivalent de sable à l'aide de la formule suivante $ES= \frac{H1}{H2} \times 100 $.
\end{enumerate}
    \begin{table}[!h]
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth, height=5cm}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}CC@{}}
\includegraphics{../LABO MEZAAD/IMG_20200716_112034_1.jpg}
\caption{Liquide Concentré.}
    &
    \includegraphics{../1200px-Equivalent-de-sable-2.svg.png}
    \caption{Les Normes de ES}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\subsubsection*{Essai Cisaillement à la boite}
On a fait cet essai après chaque prélèvement de l'échantillon à l'aide d 'une sondeuse. Il est important pour identifier les caractéristiques géotechniques du sol. Il est nécessaire pour avoir le comportement du sol de aux séismes et connaitre le dimensionnement de la fondation. Les étapes effectuées dans cet essai sont comme suite :
Il existe deux types d'essai cisaillement : Cisaillement drainé, Cisaillement non-drainé. Dans Laboratoire, on a fait seulement l'essai non-drainé.
    \begin{table}[!h]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}LC@{}}
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*, before=\vspace{-1ex}]
    \item On place sur le fond de la boite inférieur, une plaque pleine,puis une plaque perforés.
    \item On place sur ces plaques,l'échantillon du sol.
    \item  On place de meme façon les deux plaques(pleines et perforés) sur l'échantillon.
    \item On vice la boite supérieur avec la boite inférieur.
    \item On place le Piston.
\end{enumerate}
    &
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=5cm, valign=T]{../LABO MEZAAD/IMG_20200701_151254.jpg}
    \caption{Les boites de Casagrande}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

**Edit:**
Some remarks about above MWE (Minimal Working example):

- Since the real images are not known instead them are used "demo" version of images. This is enabled by adding `demo` option to package `adjustbox`. As mentioned in MWE comment, this option had to be removed in the real document (where your images are available).
- For aligning image (in the second column) with top of the `enumerate` list (in the first column) is used option `valign=T` in `includegraphics` options. This option is defined in the `\adjustbox` package and exported for use `\includegraphics` by option `export`.
- The package `adjustbox` also load package `includegraphicx`, it does not need to be loaded in document preamble again.
- In the table's columns specification are removed by `@{}` the first and the last `\tabcosep`. By them the contents in the first column is started at left text border and contents in the last (second) column ends at right text border.

Comment: It's a good way to manipulate with sapces, but the images are all black

Comment: @MohamedWassim, of course, it is demo image. In real document remove" demo option from options of the `adjustbox`.  See added comment in answer's MWE.