# vertical spacing around tabular

Tags: tables, line-spacing

I'm using a tabular to create a listing that contains two items. I noticed, however, that the line spacing before the tabular differs from the spacing after regular text. In the case before the tabular, there is only too little line space when the line does not contain a character that drops below the writing line.

Is there a way to ensure that the line spaces are the same?

EDIT:
Following the kind suggestion by David Carlisle, I removed all the `\\` and thereby elimited the underful hboxes (`\bigskip` seems to be a proper way to insert the paragraph breaks I think?). But there is still inconsistent spacing between the tabular and the preceding line:

MWE2:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}

\begin{document}
    \noindent 
    List 1 (works as wanted):
    
    \noindent
    ZZZZZZZZZZ
    
    \noindent
    ZZZZZZZZZZ\bigskip
    
    \noindent 
    List 2 -- too little line sPace above the tabular:
    
    \noindent 
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l l}
        ZZZZZZZZZZ & ZZZZZZZZZZ \\
        ZZZZZZZZZZ & ZZZZZZZZZZ 
    \end{tabular*}\bigskip
    
    \noindent 
    List 3 -- works as expected above the tabular:
    
    \noindent 
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l l}
        ZZZZZZZZZZ & ZZZZZZZZZZ \\
        ZZZZZZZZZZ & ZZZZZZZZZZ 
    \end{tabular*}

\end{document}
```

gives:
[image]

Comment: The problem is not tabular it is the misuse of `\\ ` You get at least eight warnings `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 4--8` 10000 is the _maximum_ level of badness warning about bad output, all of them are due to `\\ `

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334246/what-does-the-phrase-underfull-hbox-badness-10000-in-paragraph-actually-mea/334249#334249

Comment: I adjusted the MWE, but the problem above the tabular persists

Comment: use`[t]` option to the tabular to normalize the top spacing (normalizing top and bottom is a little harder

Comment: you are adding bigskip in horizontal mode which works but adding it in vertical mode is safer but any real document should not have bigskip and noindent just specify globally that paragaraphs are not indented and are separated by vertical space. in memoir you can use `\nonzeroparskip` and `\setlength\parindent{0pt}`

Comment: The reason why I use noindent and bigskip is because I need this formatting for only a single page in a larger document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `[t]` so the reference point of the tabular is on its first baseline and the baseline to baseline spacing above the table is naturally preserved.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{memoir}

\nonzeroparskip
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}
     
    List 1 (works as wanted):
    
    
    ZZZZZZZZZZ\\   
    ZZZZZZZZZZ
    
     
    List 2 -- too little line sPace above the tabular:
    
     
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}[t]{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l l}
        ZZZZZZZZZZ & ZZZZZZZZZZ \\
        ZZZZZZZZZZ & ZZZZZZZZZZ 
    \end{tabular*}
    
     
    List 3 -- works as expected above the tabular:
    
     
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}[t]{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l l}
        ZZZZZZZZZZ & ZZZZZZZZZZ \\
        ZZZZZZZZZZ & ZZZZZZZZZZ 
    \end{tabular*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This answer doesn't reproduce the spacing that I want because it makes the spacing in the tabular list different from the spacing in the regular list

Comment: @cktai ignore the removal of `\noindent` and `\bigskip` and just add `[t]` and if I understand correctly it will do what you want.

Comment: @cktai in particular th efirst list you had changed to two paragraphs so it gets para spacing here if you use `ZZZZ\\ ZZZZZ` then it will be a two-line spacing with the same as the other cases. I'll adjust

Comment: @cktai better ?

Comment: better, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

We can emulate your problem at TeX primitive level (without LaTeX). You insert a multiline `\vbox` into lines and you want to keep `\baseline` grid. Your example looks like:

```
XXXX\par
ZZZZ\par % these two lines are in \baseline grid
\vbox{
 \hbox{first line}
 \hbox{second line}
}
YYYY
```

This keeps the baseline grid between `second line` and `YYYY`, but not between `ZZZZ` and `first line` because `\vbox` itself behaves as single line which is too hight: baseline goes throw the last box in the `\vbox` and all material above this last box is interpreted as the height of this single line.

D. Carlisle suggests to use `\vtop` instead `\vbox` in this case. This `\vtop` behaves as single line with baseline going throw the first box inside `\vtop`. Then baseline grid between `ZZZZ` and `first line` will be OK, but this grid is corrupted between `second line` and `YYYY`. This is due to the fact that all material under the first box in `\vtop` constructs the depth of the single line.

The solution is using `\vtop` and one trick with `\prevdepth` primitive register:

```
XXXX\par
ZZZZ\par % these two lines are in \baseline grid
\vtop{
   \hbox{first line}   % this keeps baseline grid because \vtop
   \hbox{second line}
   \par \expandafter
}\expandafter\prevdepth\the\prevdepth % this keeps baseline grid because \prevdepth

YYYY
```

Comment: yes I was waiting to see if the OP needed to adjust the bottom spacing as well. If the table is set off with vertical space and you are not required to keep the following paragraph on a fixed grid layout, you can often avoid it (but +1, latex doesn't exactly help do that prevdepth trick but you know that:-)

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/583161/1090 :-)