# Underfull \hbox warning

Tags: formatting, warnings

I'm new at LaTEX. I'm learning by myself so this maybe is a beginner problem. I'm getting the warning: `underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph`

````
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}

\title{\textbf{Tham gia giải bài \\ THÁCH THỨC KỲ NÀY}}
\author{(Tạp chí Pi Tập $5$ - Số $6$ - Tháng $6$ năm $2021$)}
\date{Nguyễn Tấn Phúc}

\begin{document}

    \maketitle
    
    \section{Thông tin cá nhân}
        \begin{flushleft}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item[-] \textit{Họ và tên}: Nguyễn Tấn Phúc
                \item[-] \textit{Lớp}: $8/1$
         
            \end{itemize}
        \end{flushleft}
    
    \section{Giải bài P514 (Mức B)}
        
        \begin{itemize}
            \item \textit{\textbf{Đề bài:}} Đặt $\phi = \dfrac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$. Cho các số nguyên $a, b, c$ thỏa mãn:
            \[ \dfrac{a}{\phi} + \dfrac{b}{\phi^2} + \dfrac{c}{\phi^3} = \phi. \]
            Tính $2a + b + c$. 
                
            \item \textit{\textbf{Lời giải:}} \\
            Ta dễ dàng chứng minh được $\phi^2 - \phi - 1 = 0$, từ đó suy ra \\
            $$\dfrac{1}{\phi} = \phi - 1, \quad \dfrac{1}{\phi^2} = 1 - \dfrac{1}{\phi} = 2 - \phi, \quad \dfrac{1}{\phi^3} = \dfrac{1}{\phi} - \dfrac{1}{\phi^2} = 2\phi - 3$$ \\
            Giả thiết của bài toán tương đương với $a(\phi - 1) + b(2 - \phi) + c(2\phi - 3) = \phi$, hay 
            \[(a - b + 2c - 1)\phi = a - 2b + 3c.\]
            Vì $a - 2b + 3c$ là số hữu tỉ nên $(a - b + 2c - 1)\phi$ cũng là số hữu tỉ. Mà $\phi$ là số vô tỉ và $a - b + 2c - 1$ là số hữu tỉ nên $a - b + 2c = 1$. Do đó $a - 2b + 3c = 0$. Vậy $2a + b + c = 5(a - b + 2c) - 3(a - 2b + 3c) = \textbf{5}$.
                
        \end{itemize}
    
    \section{Giải bài P515 (Mức B)}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item \textit{\textbf{Đề bài:}} Trong hình dưới đây: $ABCD$ là hình vuông cạnh $2$; đường tròn $(O)$ có bán kính $1$ và tiếp xúc với $BC$ tại trung điểm $BC$, $M$ là một điểm di động trên $(O)$. Tìm giá trị lớn nhất của $AM$.
              
            \begin{figure}[ht]
                \label{fig:P515}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[scale = 0.35]{P515}
            \end{figure}
                
            \item \textit{\textbf{Lời giải:}} \\
            Gọi $N$ là trung điểm của đoạn thẳng $AD$. Khi đó ta dễ dàng tính được: \\
            $$AN = \dfrac{1}{2} \cdot AD = \dfrac{1}{2} \cdot 2 = 1$$ 
            $$ON = 2 + 1 = 3$$ \\
            Áp dụng định lí Pythagoras trong tam giác ANO vuông tại N, ta có: 
            $$OA = \sqrt{AN^2 + ON^2} = \sqrt{1^2 + 3^2} = \sqrt{10}$$ \\
            Sử dụng bất đẳng thức tam giác, ta có $AM \leq OA + OM = \sqrt{10} + 1 $. Đẳng thức xảy ra khi $M$ là điểm xa $A$ nhất trong hai giao điểm của $OA$ và $(O)$. Vậy giá trị lớn nhất của AM là $\sqrt{\textbf{10}} + \textbf{1}$.
            
        \end{itemize}     
        
      
\end{document}```
````

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334246/what-does-the-phrase-underfull-hbox-badness-10000-in-paragraph-actually-mea/334249#334249

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Underfull \hbox` normally means that TeX had to stretch things out to fill a line but that's not exactly what's happening in your document. In fact, we can replicate the issue by reducing things to:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
This is a test\\

\end{document}
```

The problem is that you're sprinkling `\\` all over your document when you don't need or want to. `\\` Only needs to be used in places where you need to manually specify a line break. Nearly¹ every instance of `\\` in your sample document should be removed. In particular, if you put `\\` at the end of a paragraph (and right before display math is effectively a paragraph end), LaTeX will try to fill the final line of the paragraph with nothing and give the warning your received.

You would also be well-served to use `\[`…`\]` instead of `$$`…`$$` to indicate display math. You might also want to typeset your pair of displayed equations using

```
\begin{gather*}
AN = \frac{1}{2} \cdot AD = \frac{1}{2} \cdot 2 = 1\\
ON = 2 + 1 = 3
\end{gather*}
```

Note that *here* we use `\\` since we have two lines of equations we're displaying. Also, I changed your `\dfrac` to `\frac`. You should prefer `\frac` over `\dfrac` except in those instances where you want to force a large fraction where you wouldn't ordinarily get one.

---

1. Really, *every* instance should be removed with the *possible* exception of the one in the title.

Answer (score 3):

The usage of `\\` followed by empty line is typical mistake in most LaTeX documents. The answer above says that `\\` should not be used in this way. I show, what happens at TeX level in detail.

LaTeX defines `\\` as `\hfil\break` by default and it redefines this control sequence in several different context (typically in `\halign` context it is `\cr` but it is not the point of our interest now).

The text

```
... end of paragraph\\
<empty line>
```

is interpreted by TeX as `... end paragraph\hfil\break<space>\par` The `\par` primitive removes the previous `<space>` (if exists) and adds `\penalty10000\hskip\pafillskip`. So, we have:

```
... end of paragraph\hfil\break\penalty10000\hskip\parfilskip
```

The `\hskip\parfillskip` is (by default) a flexible gab inserted at the last line of each paragraph. Now, TeX runs paragraph-breaking routine to create lines of the paragraph. The `\break` (exactly `\penalty-10000`) forces breaking. All discardable items after this breaking point are removed, i.e. first `\break` is accepted and following `\penalty10000\hskip\parfillskip` are removed. The final internal break is processed which finalizes the paragraph breaking algorithm. We have forced `\break` fllowed by final break, so there is created an empty line with no material inside and with `\hsize` width. This is underfull `\hbox`.

Authors of LaTeX documents are doing this mistake because they typically want to insert `\vskip\bigskipamount` (vertical space) at this point of typesetting. They realize that the macro `\vspace` (mentioned in LaTeX manuals) brings more complications because it is defined by `\vadjust` primitive, i.e. the paragraph is not finalized here. In general: this is bad practice to insert such exceptions of typesetting. If you need something like `\vskip\bigskipamount` at several (very good defined) places, include it to the typesetting design and create appropriate macros and settings of relevant TeX parameters.