# Conditional vertical space depending on the following environment

Tags: vertical-spacing

I defined a new command and want it to make sure that the following text or environment starts in a new line with some vertical space like the following:

```
\newcommand{\example}[1]{Somecommand\\*[1ex]}
```

This works perfectly fine for usual text,
but when using environments that come with their own spacing (like itemize),
the vertical space is too much.

So what I would like to see is that the 1ex-space is only added when there is no additional space defined for the following environment.

So basically I would like it to work like a section and it would be ideal to have the same amount of space regardless of the following environment.

Just not adding the additional space would be fine though.

Comment: never end a paragraph with `\\ ` that will produce underfull box warnings and very poor output use `\par\addvspace{1ex}`  which will add the maximum of 1ex and the space added before the following environment

Comment: Thanks David, actually using only `\par` is already doing exactly what I wanted to achieve here. Actually, I was always using `\\` everywhere. Do you have any good source where the usage is explained? Do you just use it in math or tabular environments? You are right, the `Underfull \hbox`-errors go away, but I still got the `Overfull \hbox` ones.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82664/when-to-use-par-and-when-newline-or-blank-lines/82666#82666 and  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/334249/1090

Comment: Thx, as far as I can understand, it is ok to use it for simple line-breaks as long as I don't want to end a paragraph (or insert an empty line), right?

Comment: yes `\\ ` is essentially a shorthand for `\newline` but the number of times that you want a forced line break in text is basically almost never.  In the last 30 years of tex use I must have needed to use this somewhere once or twice but I can't actually recall needing that.

Comment: I use it a lot, but it might be due to the lack of latex-expertise.