# Underfull problem

Tags: memoir, warnings

I am creating a `memoir` document that contains quotations from other authors and keep getting a warning about `Underfull box ...`. The output looks good to me but I would like to eliminate the warnings. I have tried using `\sloppy` but that had no effect.

Is there any generic way to eliminate these warnings?

I tried to provide an MWE but SE doesn't like me and I had to give up on pasting code into SE.

Comment: well you can put `\hbadness=10000`  to silence all warnings but better would be to arrange it wasn't under full

Comment: add `\showoutput` then you get a lot more box trace and you should see which box is underfull

Comment: is it badness 10000 or less than that?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Apologies for the late response but I had to get a new PC. The badness is less than or equal to 10000. I started to work along the lines `\hbadness=9000` to reduce the number of warnings, then fix the remaining bad text, and then onwards to a `\hbadness=8000` and so forth.

Comment: ok I just asked as 10000 [usually denotes a syntax error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/334249/1090) but any value less than that is just a paragraph with tricky text and has no generic answer.  I don't think this question can really be aswered in its current form.