# Remove empty lines due to preceeding paragraph at the top of the next page

Tags: paragraphs

When I write technical papers, sometimes a para ends at the last line. The "\\" of the last line from the para introduces an unnecessary empty line at the top of the next page. Can such an empty line be removed?

Comment: Don't use `\\\` for line breaks

Comment: To be more precise: a blank line in the input is the right way to end a paragraph.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\\`  if used at the end of a paragraph does not add vertical space; it adds an extra empty line of text to the paragraph (which always generates a warning that it has maximum badness 10000). As it is a line of the paragraph, it is not dropped at a page break.

Never use `\\`  at the end of a paragraph (`\\`  should only rarely be used outside tabular and math alignments).  If you require a layout (like the one on this site) that marks paragraphs with vertical space rather than by an indent on the first line, then you can use `\usepackage{parskip}` or use a class (such as the koma-script classes) that supports such a layout.

See for example

[What does the phrase "Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph" actually mean?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334246/what-does-the-phrase-underfull-hbox-badness-10000-in-paragraph-actually-mea/334249#334249)

Comment: Thank you very much. I was not even sure if double slash was actually necessary at the end of the paragraph.