# Overleaf: Line break gives overfull/underfull warning

Tags: errors

I am inserting line breaks as follows.

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet \\

New paragraph \\

Another new paragraph
```

For every new paragraph, Overleaf gives a warning. This is either of the two, sometimes both:

- Overfull \hbox (6.36636pt too wide)
- Underfull \hbox (badness 10,000)

What is causing this warning, and what is the appropriate method for new paragraphs?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  *Never* use a double backslash to end a paragraph.  The canonical defined paragraph ending is a blank line or `\par`.  A double backslash will indeed break the current line, but it will cause other problems that may or may not result in error messages.

Comment: you should almost never use `\\ ` outside of tables or math alignments, certainly never use it at the end of a paragraph as that is always an error, unfotunately only reported as a warning `Underfull \hbox (badness 10,000)` see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334246/what-does-the-phrase-underfull-hbox-badness-10000-in-paragraph-actually-mea/334249#334249

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to use `\\` to end normal lines of text. It is actually wrong.

Paragraphs are separated from each other with a blank line and no LaTeX guide can possibly recommend using `\\`, even less with a following blank line.

Just forget it. The command `\\` *can* be used for ending lines in some situations: inside `center` and the alignment environments such as `tabular`, `array`, `align,` gather` and similar ones. The difference is that in these cases ending a line must be explicitly marked, but note that this is ending *lines*, not paragraphs ending.

If your aim is to leave vertical spaces between paragraphs, load the [`parskip`](https://texdoc.org/serve/parskip/0) package (but your readers will be grateful if you don't).

Overfull boxes are a different matter: they mean that TeX couldn't find a suitable sequence of break points to fully justify a paragraph. The usual advice is to worry about them only in the very final phase of document production. Rewriting and fixing the grammar most often cures the problem.

Answer (score 1):

When a paragraph ends by `\\` in LaTeX then LaTeX defines `\\` as `\hfil\break` and TeX adds final `\unskip\nobreak\hskip\prafilskip\break` from following `\par` command. So, we have at the end of the paragraph:

```
...last word.\hfil\break\nobreak\hskip\parfillskip\break
```

and the line is broken at the first `\break`. The following `\hskip\parfillskip` is a discardable element, it is removed. We have the last `\break` immediatelly after previous `\break`. The line between those two breaks must be set to the width `\hsize` but there is no material in it. This is the reason of `Underfull \hbox` and this is very common mistake of LaTeX beginners if they don't know nothing about TeX.