# How to avoid an extra line number when breaking page (lineno package)

Tags: page-breaking, lineno

I'm using `lineno` to number lines, but sometimes I have to force a page break inside a paragraph and for that I use `\break\newpage\noindent`. The page break is perfect, but
`lineno` adds an extra line number after the `break` command, how can I avoid this?

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pagewise]{lineno}
\def\mybreakline{\break\newpage\noindent}
\begin{document}

\begin{linenumbers}

Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla

Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla\mybreakline bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla

\end{linenumbers}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: why `\break\newpage\noindent.`  rather than `\pagebreak` ?

Comment: Because I have some footnotes generated by manyfoot and when I used `\pagebreak` they move up.

Comment: probably fixable, but `\let\mybreakline\pagebreak` removes the badness 10000 warning and empty line, so that line (24) gets text, I am not sure if you want that or page 1 to stop at 23. in which case you would need to move `\mybreakline` (`\pagebreak`) a bit earlier

Comment: How about `\def\mybreakline{\par\newpage\noindent}` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have

```
\def\mybreakline{\break\newpage\noindent}
```

`\newpage` ends the pargraph so this adds `\break` after the final line so forces an empty line of text. As in

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/334249/1090

`lineno` isn't causing the extra line, just numbering it.

To end the paragraph without leaving the last line short you could use

```
\def\mybreakline{{\parfillskip=0pt\newpage}\noindent}
```

[image]

But better really is to use

```
\let\mybreakline\pagebreak
```

which forces a page break without ending the paragraph or forcing a line break. As the page break happens after the natural line break you get 24 lines of text here, but you could move the command earlier if you want 23.