# Underfull \hbox (badness 1389) in paragraph

Tags: line-breaking, tex-core

I am trying to draw a table like:
[image]

However, there is a warning in line 117 that "Underfull \hbox (badness 1389) in paragraph "
[image]

When I searched this error, [it says that 99% I put \\ wrong](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334246/what-does-the-phrase-underfull-hbox-badness-10000-in-paragraph-actually-mea).

I think I put \\ correctly, because there is 3 columns.
(ex. A & B & C \\ )

May I ask what's wrong with my script?

Comment: this is not an error but a warning. The answer you link to is specifically about the value 10000 (maximum) which is unlikely to happen by chance. 1389 is not very bad at all and quite likely to occur in narrow columns. It is just telling you that the word spaces on the line `A soccer..`  are a bit more stretched than usual

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an error but a warning. The answer you link to is specifically about the value 10000 (maximum) which is unlikely to happen by chance. 1389 is not very bad at all and quite likely to occur in narrow columns. It is just telling you that the word spaces on the line

> A soccer..

are a bit more stretched than usual

By default latex allows lines of badness up to 1000 but warns if white space stretching makes badness more than that, so 1389 is only just over this. You could replace `m{5cm}` by `>{\hbadness=5000 }m{5cm}` so the warning is silenced or you could use `>{\raggedright}m{5cm}`  so the text is not justfied and word spaces are not stretched.