# Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph: removing the `\\`and still having the right expected rendition

Tags: indentation, vertical-spacing

I am having the following error messages:

```
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active [78]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 3836--3837

Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active [79]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 3853--3854 [80]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 3901--3902

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 3915--3920

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 3921--3922

Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active [81]

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 3950--3951

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 3956--3957

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 3961--3963

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 3963--3964

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 3974--3975 [82]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 4028--4029

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 4054--4057

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 4073--4078

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 4082--4086

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 4087--4088

Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active [83]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 4093--4097

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 4112--4113

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 4114--4115


Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active [84]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 4148--4151


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 4156--4157


Underfull \vbox (badness 3872) has occurred while \output is active [85]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 4173--4178

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 4179--4183 [86] [87] [88] Chapitre 5.

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 4261--4262

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 4269--4270

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 4270--4271

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 4272--4273

Underfull \hbox (badness 1077) in paragraph at lines 4286--486
 []|$\OML/ztmcm/m/it/10 Q$ $\OMS/ztmcm/m/n/10 ^^B$|

Underfull \hbox (badness 2050) in paragraph at lines 4286--4286
 []|$\OT1/ztmcm/m/n/10 ^^F$|

Underfull \hbox (badness 1924) in paragraph at lines 4286--4286
 []|$\OML/ztmcm/m/it/10 Q$|
[89]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 4292--4294

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 4337--4339 [90] [91] [92]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 4494--4495
```

I tried using

> \usepackage{parskip}

but it doesn't fix the errors messages.

I have checked many of the question about this error message here `Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while` but none of them helped me to fixed out my errors.

Below is an example of code reproducing the errors messages:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=20cm, paperheight=29cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}

            \begin{enumerate}
                \item [] \textbf{Phase 1: analyse lexicale}
                    Les jetons de l'expression précédente sont identifiés ainsi qu'il suit par l'analyseur lexical:

            L'analyseur lexical établit ensuite l'arbre de dérivation de cette dernière expression obtenue. Cet arbre est représenté ainsi:

                \begin{figure}  
                    \Tree [.= 
                                    [.$id_1$ ]
                                    [.+
                                        [.$id_2$ ]
                                        [.$^*$ 
                                            [.$id_3$ ]
                                            [.50 ] 
                                            ] ] ] 
                \end{figure}

            L'arbre de dérivation généré est transmis à l'analyseur syntaxique.
\\
            \item [] \textbf{Phase 2: analyse syntaxique}
\\

            L'analyseur syntaxique reçoit en entrée l'arbre de dérivation élaboré précédemment et vérifie si l'expression analysée est dans le bon ordre et est correcte selon les règles de grammaire du langage.

            Si l'arbre de dérivation a été fait correctement alors la syntaxe de la phase 2 est sans erreur.

            Si la syntaxe de l'arbre est correcte alors le processus de compilation se poursuit à la phase suivante. Sinon un message d'erreur de syntaxe est généré.

                \Tree [.= 
                                [.$id_1$ ]
                                [.+
                                    [.$id_2$ ]
                                    [.$^*$ 
                                        [.$id_3$ ]
                                        [.50 ] 
                                        ] ] ] 

            \item [] \textbf{Phase 3: analyse sémantique}
\\

            \item [] \textbf{Phase 4: génération du code intermédiaire}
\\

            \item [] \textbf{Phase 5: optimisation de code}
\\

                Il y a des redondances dans le code issu de la phase précédente. Il faut l'optimiser. De 4 instructions on passe à 2 instructions ainsi qu'il suit:
                
                L'instruction de conversion du nombre 50 en réel a disparu, mais à cette étape le processus de conversion est déjà effectué.

            \item [] \textbf{Phase 4: génération du code machine}
                \begin{verbatim}
                    MOV R2, id_3
                    MUL R2, #50
                    MOV R1, id_2
                    ADD R1, R2
                    MOV id_1, R1
                \end{verbatim}
            \end{enumerate}

~\\         \begin{enumerate}
                \item Les langages réguliers de type 3, sont strictement contenus dans les langages algébriques, de type 2;
                \item Les langages algébriques propres, de type 2, sont strictement contenus dans les langages contextuels, de type 1;
                \item les langages contextuels, de type 1, sont strictement contenus dans les langages récursifs;
                \item les langages récursifs sont strictement contenus dans les langages récursivement énumérables, de type 0.
            \end{enumerate}

            Exemples de mots:
~\\

            Les langages algébriques propres, de type 2, sont strictement contenus dans les langages contextuels, de type 1;
            les langages contextuels, de type 1, sont strictement contenus dans les langages récursifs;

~\\
            En outre, dans le cas de l'interprétation, le code généré est multi-plateforme, il suffit que les utilisateurs disposent de l'interpréteur sur leur ordinateur. Par exemple, en considérant le cas du langage JavaScript, tous les utilisateurs d'un ordinateur disposent d'un navigateur web sur leur poste de travail. Dans le navigateur web, est incorporé un interpréteur JavaScript. Donc si un code source écrit.

            ~\\
            Ensuite, un autre avantage à utiliser un interpréteur, c'est que le programme écrit est très facile à tester. 


~\\         \begin{enumerate}
                \item Les langages réguliers de type 3, sont strictement contenus dans les langages algébriques, de type 2;
                \item Les langages algébriques propres, de type 2, sont strictement contenus dans les langages contextuels, de type 1;
                \item les langages contextuels, de type 1, sont strictement contenus dans les langages récursifs;
                \item les langages récursifs sont strictement contenus dans les langages récursivement énumérables, de type 0.
            \end{enumerate}

            ~\\

            lang.age = langage

        La concaténation et le produit sont associatifs, distributifs à droite et à gauche pour l'union et sont nonncommutatifs. L’élément neutre du produit est $\epsilon$ et l'élément absorbant $\emptyset$.

            En outre, dans le cas de l'interprétation, le code généré est multi-plateforme, il suffit que les utilisateurs disposent de l'interpréteur sur leur ordinateur. Par exemple, en considérant le cas du langage JavaScript, tous les utilisateurs d'un ordinateur disposent d'un navigateur web sur leur poste de travail. Dans le navigateur web, est incorporé un interpréteur JavaScript. Donc si un code source écrit.

            ~\\
                    Imaginons que nous lisons un programme et faisons ce qu'il dit de faire étape par étape

~\\             Avec $\delta$ définie ainsi qu'il suit:
~\\
                $\delta = \{\\
                \delta (s, 0) = t, \\
                \delta (s, 1) = t, \\
                \delta (s, 2) = t, \\
                \delta (t, 0) = s, \\
                \delta (t, 1) = s, \\
                \delta (t, 2) = s$ \\ \}

~\\         Dessinez l'automate correspondant.\\
~\\         Quel est le langage de mots reconnus par cet automate?
~\\
                \emph{Réponse:} \\

                Cet automate reconnaît l'ensemble des mots de longueur impair, formés de 0, 1, 2.\\

                Dessinez l'automate qui reconnaît ce langage de mots: \\
~\\
                \emph{Réponse:} \\
\end{document}
```

Thank you.

I have read the 3 suggested answer link before posting my question. The problem is the fact that if I simply remove the `\\` as suggested in the referred answers, the text cannot be indented vertically to be readable as needed.

As attachment is showed the display I want to get.[image]

Comment: Remove all those ``\\``

Comment: Duplicate: [What does the phrase "Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph" actually mean?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/334246)

Comment: on your edit you should remove all the `\\ ` which are generating the warnings and bad output that you asked about. If you said what layout you wanted as a new question someone would answer, eg your `\delta (s, 0)` block should probably use `align` environment.

Comment: My question is not about the meaning of the errors, but how to remove the `\\`and still having the right expected rendition.

Comment: @cProg ... then it might be better if you would edit your question to ask how to get your desired results, e.g. something like "How to increase the space between these two lines?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using LaTeX as if it were a word processor. It isn't.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=20cm, paperheight=29cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\phase}[1]{\par\medskip\textbf{#1}\par\nopagebreak}


\begin{document}

\phase{Phase 1: analyse lexicale}

Les jetons de l'expression précédente sont identifiés ainsi qu'il suit par l'analyseur lexical:

L'analyseur lexical établit ensuite l'arbre de dérivation de cette dernière expression 
obtenue. Cet arbre est représenté ainsi:
\[
  \Tree [.= 
         [.$id_1$ ]
          [.+
           [.$id_2$ ]
           [.$^*$ 
            [.$id_3$ ]
            [.50 ] 
           ]
          ]
         ] 
\]
L'arbre de dérivation généré est transmis à l'analyseur syntaxique.

\phase{Phase 2: analyse syntaxique}

L'analyseur syntaxique reçoit en entrée l'arbre de dérivation élaboré 
précédemment et vérifie si l'expression analysée est dans le bon ordre 
et est correcte selon les règles de grammaire du langage.

Si l'arbre de dérivation a été fait correctement alors la syntaxe de la phase 2 est sans erreur.

Si la syntaxe de l'arbre est correcte alors le processus de compilation se poursuit 
à la phase suivante. Sinon un message d'erreur de syntaxe est généré.
\[
                \Tree [.= 
                                [.$id_1$ ]
                                [.+
                                    [.$id_2$ ]
                                    [.$^*$ 
                                        [.$id_3$ ]
                                        [.50 ] 
                                        ] ] ] 
\]
\phase{Phase 3: analyse sémantique}

\phase{Phase 4: génération du code intermédiaire}

\phase{Phase 5: optimisation de code}

Il y a des redondances dans le code issu de la phase précédente. Il faut l'optimiser. 
De 4 instructions on passe à 2 instructions ainsi qu'il suit:
                
L'instruction de conversion du nombre 50 en réel a disparu, mais à cette étape le 
processus de conversion est déjà effectué.

\phase{Phase 4: génération du code machine}
\begin{verbatim}
    MOV R2, id_3
    MUL R2, #50
    MOV R1, id_2
    ADD R1, R2
    MOV id_1, R1
\end{verbatim}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Les langages réguliers de type 3, sont strictement contenus dans 
les langages algébriques, de type 2;

\item Les langages algébriques propres, de type 2, sont strictement 
contenus dans les langages contextuels, de type 1;

\item les langages contextuels, de type 1, sont strictement contenus 
dans les langages récursifs;

\item les langages récursifs sont strictement contenus dans les langages 
récursivement énumérables, de type 0.
\end{enumerate}

Exemples de mots:\par\nopagebreak

Les langages algébriques propres, de type 2, sont strictement contenus 
dans les langages contextuels, de type 1; les langages contextuels, 
de type 1, sont strictement contenus dans les langages récursifs;

En outre, dans le cas de l'interprétation, le code généré est multi-plateforme, 
il suffit que les utilisateurs disposent de l'interpréteur sur leur ordinateur. 
Par exemple, en considérant le cas du langage JavaScript, tous les utilisateurs 
d'un ordinateur disposent d'un navigateur web sur leur poste de travail. Dans 
le navigateur web, est incorporé un interpréteur JavaScript. Donc si un code source écrit.

Ensuite, un autre avantage à utiliser un interpréteur, c'est que le programme 
écrit est très facile à tester. 


\begin{enumerate}
\item Les langages réguliers de type 3, sont strictement contenus dans 
les langages algébriques, de type 2;

\item Les langages algébriques propres, de type 2, sont strictement 
contenus dans les langages contextuels, de type 1;

\item les langages contextuels, de type 1, sont strictement contenus 
dans les langages récursifs;

\item les langages récursifs sont strictement contenus dans les langages 
récursivement énumérables, de type 0.
\end{enumerate}

lang.age = langage

La concaténation et le produit sont associatifs, distributifs à droite 
et à gauche pour l'union et sont nonncommutatifs. L’élément neutre du 
produit est $\epsilon$ et l'élément absorbant $\emptyset$.

En outre, dans le cas de l'interprétation, le code généré est multi-plateforme, 
il suffit que les utilisateurs disposent de l'interpréteur sur leur ordinateur. 
Par exemple, en considérant le cas du langage JavaScript, tous les utilisateurs 
d'un ordinateur disposent d'un navigateur web sur leur poste de travail. Dans 
le navigateur web, est incorporé un interpréteur JavaScript. Donc si un code 
source écrit.

Imaginons que nous lisons un programme et faisons ce qu'il dit de faire étape par étape

Avec $\delta$ définie ainsi qu'il suit:
\[
  \begin{aligned}
    \delta = \{&\\
               & \delta (s, 0) = t, \\
               & \delta (s, 1) = t, \\
               & \delta (s, 2) = t, \\
               & \delta (t, 0) = s, \\
               & \delta (t, 1) = s, \\
               & \delta (t, 2) = s \\
             \}
  \end{aligned}
\]
Dessinez l'automate correspondant.

Quel est le langage de mots reconnus par cet automate?

\emph{Réponse:}

Cet automate reconnaît l'ensemble des mots de longueur impair, formés de 0, 1, 2.

Dessinez l'automate qui reconnaît ce langage de mots:

\emph{Réponse:}

\end{document}
```

[image]