# Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph within nested minipages

Tags: paragraphs, warnings, box

I am generating a [PDF](https://siouxfallsaa.org/meeting-schedule.pdf) using a [.tex file](https://siouxfallsaa.org/meeting-schedule.tex) of similar name.

Generating the PDF with pdflatex generates a number of `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 539--542`, with each set of line numbers referring to a minipage block.

```
      \begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
        \vskip 1ex\textbf{GenZoom Recovery\hfill\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-27ex\relax}\raggedleft \mbox{6:30PM}\end{minipage}}
        Zoom-Only\hfill WA\\{\6pt
        We meet daily for quick and short meetings to help each other through the work day.}
      \end{minipage}
      \begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
        \vskip 1ex\textbf{Broken Meeting No.1\hfill\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-27ex\relax}\raggedleft \mbox{6:30PM}\end{minipage}}
        Guiding Schoolhouse\hfill WA\\
        567 Beacon Lane, Nurtureville, NV, 89007
      \end{minipage}
```

I suspect this has to do with using a minipage inside of a minipage in order to get times/tags aligned to the right side. I read that trailing/unused `\\` can cause these warnings, but removing them didn't seem to produce any change.

Full example, as requested:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=0.25in]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\def\6pt{\fontsize{6}{7.2}\selectfont}
\def\7pt{\fontsize{7}{8}\selectfont}
\def\8pt{\fontsize{8.5}{10}\selectfont}
\def\gutter{\hspace{0.02\textwidth}}

\fontfamily{phv}\fontseries{mc}\selectfont
\begin{document}

  {\textbf{Meetings}}\hrulefill\vskip 1ex
  \begin{multicols}{4}
    
    \vskip 2ex{\8pt\textbf{Sunday}}\hrulefill\vskip 1ex
    {\7pt
      \begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
        \vskip 1ex\textbf{Serenity Path AA\hfill\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-27ex\relax}\raggedleft \mbox{6:30PM}\end{minipage}}\\
        Harmony Church\hfill WA\\
        345 Ascend Street, Serenity Springs, NV, 89007\\
      \end{minipage}
      \begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
        \vskip 1ex\textbf{GenZoom Recovery\hfill\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-27ex\relax}\raggedleft \mbox{6:30PM}\end{minipage}}\\
        Zoom-Only\hfill WA\\{\6pt
        We meet daily for quick and short meetings to help each other through the work day.}
      \end{minipage}
    }
  \end{multicols}
  

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE! Please, extend your code snippet to complete small document, which reproduce your problem(s).

Comment: Pleas provide an sketch what you after. From your code snippet this is not possible to figured out.

Comment: What is the `{\6pt` at the end of the third line?

Comment: Now your document example not throes any warnings, What is than a problem?

Comment: you do realise you are defining `\6` not `\6pt`?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334246/what-does-the-phrase-underfull-hbox-badness-10000-in-paragraph-actually-mea/334249#334249

Answer (score 4):

I can explain you why there are two Underfull \hbox warnings when your full example is processed.

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 27--30


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 26--37
```

First one is due to your bad `\\` at the end of line 29. The `\\` is defined as `\hfil\break` in this context and this creates empty line in the paragraph which is underfull. More exact explanation needs to understand deeply the paragraph breaking algorithm in TeX, it is not only for short explanation. The main message is: the paragraph cannot end by `\\`.

The second Underfull message is here because you have four columns declared by `\begin{multicols}` but only material for three columns is available. If you add a line before `\end{multicols}` with something, for example:

```
   ...
   }
  something
  \end{multicols}
  ...
```

then the second Underfull message disappear.

Note that if you define

```
\def\6pt{...}
```

then you don't define the control sequence `\6pt` but only the control sequence `\6` which is macro with the obligatory parameter `pt`. It works in your case but it seems that there is misunderstanding how TeX tokenizer works and how macros are defined.

Answer (score 1):

You have `\\`  at the end of a paragraph generating an underful box, but more generally the `multicols` and nested minipages are not helping. If you simplfy the markup it is easier to avoid empty boxes.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=0.25in]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\def\sixpt{\fontsize{6}{7.2}\selectfont}
\def\sevenpt{\fontsize{7}{8}\selectfont}
\def\eightpt{\fontsize{8.5}{10}\selectfont}
\def\gutter{\hspace{0.02\textwidth}}

\fontfamily{phv}\fontseries{mc}\selectfont
\begin{document}


\textbf{Meetings}\hrulefill\vspace{1ex}

    
\sevenpt
\begin{minipage}[t]{.235\columnwidth}
    \eightpt\textbf{Sunday}\hrulefill
\end{minipage}\gutter
\begin{minipage}[t]{.235\columnwidth}
\textbf{Serenity Path AA\hfill 6:30PM}\par
        Harmony Church\hfill WA\par
\sixpt  345 Ascend Street, Serenity Springs, NV, 89007
\end{minipage}\gutter
\begin{minipage}[t]{.235\columnwidth}
\textbf{GenZoom Recovery\hfill 6:30PM}\par
        Zoom-Only\hfill WA\par
\sixpt    We meet daily for quick and short meetings to help each other through the work day.
\end{minipage}



  

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do define commands for such jobs!

You don't need nested minipages and guesswork about the spacing. The following accommodates three meetings per line, if more are on some day they're set under the others.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,letterpaper]{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % <-- no longer needed
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=0.25in]{geometry}

%\usepackage{anyfontsize}% <-- obsolete and useless with mathptmx
\usepackage{mathptmx}
%\usepackage{multicol}% <-- not needed
\usepackage{microtype}

\newcommand{\sixpt}{\fontsize{6}{7.2}\selectfont}
\newcommand{\sevenpt}{\fontsize{7}{8}\selectfont}
\newcommand{\eightpt}{\fontsize{8.5}{10}\selectfont}

\newcommand{\gutter}{1em}
\newcommand{\WIDTH}{\dimeval{(\textwidth-\dimeval{\gutter}*3)/4}}

\newcommand{\DAY}[1]{%
  \par\addvspace{2ex}%
  \hspace*{-\leftskip}%
  \makebox[\WIDTH][l]{\eightpt\bfseries #1\hrulefill}%
  \hspace{\gutter}\ignorespaces
}
\newcommand{\MEETING}[5]{%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\WIDTH}
  \setlength{\lineskip}{1pt}
  \sevenpt
  {\bfseries #1\hfill #2\par}
  {#3\hfill #4\par}
  #5
  \end{minipage}\hspace{\gutter plus 2pt minus 2pt}\ignorespaces
}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setlength{\leftskip}{\dimeval{\WIDTH+\gutter}}%
  \setlength{\lineskip}{1ex}%
}

%\fontfamily{phv}\fontseries{mc}\selectfont % <-- does nothing at all

\begin{document}

\hspace*{-\leftskip}\textbf{Meetings}\hrulefill

\vspace{1ex}
    
\DAY{Sunday}
\MEETING{Serenity Path AA}{6:30PM}{Harmony Church}{WA}{
  345 Ascend Street, Serenity Springs, NV, 89007
}
\MEETING{GenZoom Recovery}{6:30PM}{Zoom-Only}{WA}{
  \sixpt
   We meet daily for quick and short meetings to help each other through the work day.
}

\DAY{Monday}
\MEETING{Serenity Path AA}{6:30PM}{Harmony Church}{WA}{
  345 Ascend Street, Serenity Springs, NV, 89007
}
\MEETING{GenZoom Recovery}{6:30PM}{Zoom-Only}{WA}{
  \sixpt
   We meet daily for quick and short meetings to help each other through the work day.
}
\MEETING{GenZoom Recovery}{6:30PM}{Zoom-Only}{WA}{
  \sixpt
   We meet daily for quick and short meetings to help each other through the work day.
}

\DAY{Tuesday}
\MEETING{Serenity Path AA}{6:30PM}{Harmony Church}{WA}{
  345 Ascend Street, Serenity Springs, NV, 89007
}
\MEETING{Serenity Path AA}{6:30PM}{Harmony Church}{WA}{
  345 Ascend Street, Serenity Springs, NV, 89007
}
\MEETING{GenZoom Recovery}{6:30PM}{Zoom-Only}{WA}{
  \sixpt
   We meet daily for quick and short meetings to help each other through the work day.
}
\MEETING{GenZoom Recovery}{6:30PM}{Zoom-Only}{WA}{
  \sixpt
   We meet daily for quick and short meetings to help each other through the work day.
}

\end{document}
```

The gutter between columns is parameterized so you can change it in a single place. The column widths are computed accordingly.

Please, check the `<--` tags in the code and remove those parts. For instance, `anyfontsize` is obsolete and useless anyway when you load scalable fonts such as those provided by `mathptmx`.

[image]

Note that `\def\6pt{...}` is accepted by TeX, but I cannot recommend using it.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

**Edit:**

- Thank you for editing question.
- Provided document example works doesn't generate any warnings, however throw two bad boxes.
- Your code in is unnecessary complicated.
- In my MWE below I remove all `\mbox`es and nested mini pages.
- So, MWE which not produce your problem, can be:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=0.25in]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}     % <----
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\def\6pt{\fontsize{6}{7.2}\selectfont}
\def\7pt{\fontsize{7}{8}\selectfont}
\def\8pt{\fontsize{8.5}{10}\selectfont}
\def\gutter{\hspace{0.02\textwidth}}

\fontfamily{phv}
\fontseries{mc}\selectfont
\begin{document}
Nunc sed pede. Praesent vitae lectus. Praesent neque justo, vehicula eget, interdum id, facilisis et, nibh. Phasellus at purus et libero lacinia dictum. Fusce aliquet. Nulla eu ante placerat leo semper dictum. Mauris metus. Curabitur lobortis. Curabitur sollicitudin hendrerit nunc. Donec ultrices lacus id ipsum.

\textbf{Meetings}\hrulefill

\vskip 1ex
\begin{multicols}{4}
\vskip 2ex
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\8pt
\textbf{Sunday}             \hrulefill
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\7pt
\textbf{Serenity Path AA}   \hfill 6:30PM   \\
Harmony Church              \hfill WA       \\
345 Ascend Street, Serenity Springs, NV, 89007 
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
\textbf{GenZoom Recovery}   \hfill 6:30PM   \\
Zoom-Only                   \hfill WA       \\
\6pt
We meet daily for quick and short meetings to help each other through the work day.
\end{minipage}
  \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

It not produce any warnings nor bad boxes

[image]

BTW, are you sure that you need for columns? Are for your example are not sufficient just three?

Comment: The basic "design" I was trying to accomplish was having time/tags float in the top-right, so that they can "flow around" long meeting names. [ I'm not sure why "imagination" is required for what I'm after. I understand that sharing a link to the PDF can be problematic for the future, but are you saying that it can't be seen now? ]

That "lonely \6pt" was because this is ultimately going into a template and whitespace in the output isn't exactly perfect (yet). It is applies to and is closed by the } on the next line.

Comment: I don't see any way to attach the images you are asking for without uploading somewhere else to share a link ...

Comment: @MTecknology, sorry, your question is unclear. Code fragment is broken (can not be compiled) , no provided information about used document class nor about page layout, etc. Image is simple insert to question. If yo use Windows OS, than by Snipping tool cut image from your pdf image of document and past into question .  What is now more important: does my answer solve your problem?

Comment: I don't think it answered my question (and not on Windows). So far, I tried to focus on \noindent, but mostly just reading. I provided a link to a PDF showing the output (which is desired) as well as the .tex file that was used to produce it, but you pointed out that those are externally hosted so not okay ... but I don't see any way to share any image without such a service.

Comment: @MTecknology you can add images via pasting or use ctrl-g or the image button in the editor to upload an image ifile