# Getting "Package tabularx Warning: X Columns too narrow (table too wide)" and not sure how to fix, LaTeX

Tags: tabularx

Package tabularx Warning: X Columns too narrow (table too wide) on line ****

```
\rightheader{~}

\begin{fullonly}

\end{fullonly}

\title{Curriculum Vitae}

\begin{document}

%\hyphenchar\font=-1

\makeheaders[c]

***\makerubric{experience}

\makerubric{education}
```

Also getting, refering to the first error:

```
Overfull \hbox (9.18pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 3--4

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 3--4

Overfull \hbox (19.51994pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 3--4

Overfull \hbox (7.23997pt too wide) in paragraph at lines
```

The settings:

````
\RequirePackage{silence}

\WarningsOff[longtable]

\WarningsOff[array]

\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}

\newif\ifxetexorluatex

\ifxetex

\xetexorluatextrue

\else

\ifluatex

\xetexorluatextrue
\else

\xetexorluatexfalse
\fi

\fi

\RequirePackage{graphicx}

\RequirePackage[hyphens]{url}

\RequirePackage{babel}

\raggedright

\RequirePackage[fixed]{fontawesome5}

\newcommand{\smallcaps}[1]{\textsc{\lowercase{#1}}}

\RequirePackage[a4paper,nohead,nofoot,hmargin=1.27cm,vmargin=1.27cm]{geometry}

\RequirePackage{relsize}

\RequirePackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}

\RequirePackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shadows}

\RequirePackage{comment}

\definecolor{SwishLineColour}{HTML}{283583}

\definecolor{MarkerColour}{HTML}{B6073F}

\RequirePackage{csquotes}

\RequirePackage{tikz}

\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{

\node[shape=circle,text=white,fill=MarkerColour!80!black,font=\sffamily\scriptsize\bfseries,inner sep=1pt,text height=1.25ex,minimum width=1.25em,text centered] (char) {#1};}}

\headerscale{1}

%\setlength{\headerspace}{6pt}

\rubricfont{\Large\bfseries\sffamily}

\setlength{\rubricspace}{0pt}

%\setlength{\rubricafterspace}{-9pt}

\setlength{\rubricafterspace}{-10pt}

\setlength{\subrubricspace}{3pt}

\setlength{\subrubricbeforespace}{4pt}

\def@@rubrichead#1{%

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]%\

\shade[left color=SwishLineColour!60!white, right color=white] rectangle (@almosttextwidth,2.5pt);

\node[font={@rubricfont},inner sep=0pt,text ragged,anchor=south west,text depth=.5ex,text height=1.5ex] at (1pt,2pt) {#1};

\end{tikzpicture}%

\vspace\rubricspace%

}

\subrubricfont{\large\bfseries\sffamily}

\subrubricalignment{l}

\newcommand{\makefield}[2]{\makebox[1.5em]{\color{MarkerColour!80!black}#1} #2\hspace{2em}}

\keyalignment{r}

\rubricalignment{l}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}

\urlstyle{tt}

% \newcommand{\prefixmarker}[1]{\def@prefixmarker{#1}}

% \def@prefixmarker{\relscale{.9}\faBookmark}

\prefix{%

\hspace*{-1ex}

% \color{MarkerColour!80!black}@prefixmarker%

\hspace*{1ex}%

}

\newcommand{\makerubrichead}[1]{\vskip\baselineskip@@rubrichead{#1}}

\RequirePackage{pgffor}

\newcommand{\mynames}[1]{\def\my@namelist{#1}}

\newtoggle{boldname}

\RequirePackage[colorlinks=true,allcolors=black,breaklinks=true]{hyperref}```

Fix the error ... not sure how to fix the settings
````

Comment: You have posted a lot of code but none of it related to your question. Post a small self contained document just making a single table that gives this warning (preferably using article class) and someone will help you reformat it to fit.

Comment: `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 3--4` is probably a mis-placed `\\ ` see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334246/what-does-the-phrase-underfull-hbox-badness-10000-in-paragraph-actually-mea/334249#334249

Comment: You are showing your general document settings but the warning is just about the content in one specific table that does not fit in the space provided, showing your document settings and non standard commands with no hint of their definition such as `\makerubric` will not help anyone suggest how to reformat your table.

Comment: The three overfull-hbox warnings could be due to several reasons. The warnings could be happening in just one column, or they could be occurring in two or more columns. Unless you show the complete code of the `tabularx` environment, starting with `\begin{tabularx}` and ending with `\end{tabularx}`, and also provide information about the document class type, the main document font size, the width of the text block, and any hyphenation (or hyphenation suppression) settings, there's little that can be stated in terms of specific advice on how to fix the overfull-hbox issues.