# \mathfrak didn't show correctly. (e.g., \mathfrak{0} in the tex file shows \mathfrak{5} in the generated pdf)

Tags: math-fonts, displaystyle

Here is the text in the .tex file:

`by learning multiple functions $\{f_\rho^{\mathfrak{0}}, f_\rho^{\mathfrak{1}}, \cdots, f_\rho^{\mathfrak{K}} \}$`

Here is the strange output in the pdf file:
[image]

Here are the environment used in the tex file:

```
\documentclass{sokendai_thesis} % https://github.com/koikezlemma/phd_thesis_template/blob/master/sokendai_thesis.cls


\begin{document}

by learning multiple functions $\{f_\rho^{\mathfrak{0}}, f_\rho^{\mathfrak{1}}, \cdots, f_\rho^{\mathfrak{K}} \}$ \\

$\forall{\mathfrak{k}}\in\{\mathfrak{0},\cdots, \mathfrak{K}\}$. 

\end{document}
```

Does anyone know a possible reason for such strange output? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! You've given us a fragment of code but that's not terribly useful for diagnosis. Can you edit your question and provide a complete minimal document we can compile to reproduce the output you show? This should begin `\documentclass...` and end `\end{document}` for LaTeX. In that sense, you've not provided enough; but you've also given too much. Likely you don't need all of those packages to reproduce the problem, so you should also remove the ones you don't need before posting your edited example here.

Comment: Try adding the instruction `\usepackage{amssymb}` to the preamble.

Comment: @Mico Thanks. But then I got the conflict error: ```LaTeX Error: Command `\Bbbk' already defined.``` I also tried 'amsmath' and 'amsfonts', but doesn't help.

Comment: Where in the preamble did you insert the instruction `\usepackage{amssymb}`? Toward the beginning, or toward the end? Incidentally, the `amssymb` package loads the `amsfonts` package automatically. By the way, would you mind revealing which document class you employ? (It's the main argument of the `\documentclass` instruction.)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Well, the "K" is a "K", writtten as some kind of so called fractura. This is one of the handwriting monchs, and other people, usedd during the middle-ages, and which was used in the first printed versions of and after Gutenberg. BTW, the print was perceived as being less good (inferior) than the handwriting at that time ...

Comment: Hi @Mico, Thanks for reply! I tried inserting `amssymb` towards the beginning (as did in the line 30 of sokendai_thesis.cls). and the document class I am using is from https://github.com/koikezlemma/phd_thesis_template/blob/master/sokendai_thesis.cls

Comment: I edited your example to be more reasonable, it produces the same output.  Note it gives an underfull hbox message see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334246/what-does-the-phrase-underfull-hbox-badness-10000-in-paragraph-actually-mea/334249#334249

Comment: What should `\mathfrak{0}` or `\mathfrak{1}` even look like? Fraktur style in math mode is typically only used for letters, not so much for numbers, at least to my knowledge. (Also, numbers in Fraktur do not look much differently from numbers in Antiqua, so it might not be the best choice if disambiguation is important.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you copy the packages used in the class to the preamble and then delete any that you can delete while still showing the problem you end up with

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{libertine} 
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}


\begin{document}

by learning multiple functions $\{f_\rho^{\mathfrak{0}}, f_\rho^{\mathfrak{1}}, \cdots, f_\rho^{\mathfrak{K}} \}$

$\forall{\mathfrak{k}}\in\{\mathfrak{0},\cdots, \mathfrak{K}\}$. 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Simplest is to add \mathfrak back from amsfonts

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{libertine} 
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}

\let\mathfrak\relax
\usepackage{eufrak}

\begin{document}

by learning multiple functions $\{f_\rho^{\mathfrak{0}}, f_\rho^{\mathfrak{1}}, \cdots, f_\rho^{\mathfrak{K}} \}$

$\forall{\mathfrak{k}}\in\{\mathfrak{0},\cdots, \mathfrak{K}\}$. 

\end{document}
```

so it looks like an error in newtx

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's works!

Answer (score 2):

The AMS Fraktur font has glyphs for digits, the font `newtxmath` uses with the `libertine` option hasn't them and has blackboard bold digits instead (but not in the standard places, because `\mathbb` works differently than in `amsfonts`).

Here's the Fraktur font used by `libertine`:

[image]

Here's the AMS Euler Fraktur:

[image]

They're not really alike, so you may want to keep the `libertine` ones and just replace the digits. In order to blend with the heaviness of the `libertine` fonts I use the bold version.

```
\documentclass{sokendai_thesis} % https://github.com/koikezlemma/phd_thesis_template/blob/master/sokendai_thesis.cls

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \NewCommandCopy\TXmathfrak\mathfrak
  \RenewCommandCopy\mathfrak\ZLINmathfrak
}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\ZLINmathfrak}{m}
 {
  \tl_map_function:nN { #1 } \zlin_mathfrak:n
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \zlin_mathfrak:n
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {0}{\__zlin_mathfrak_digit:n { 0 }}
    {1}{\__zlin_mathfrak_digit:n { 1 }}
    {2}{\__zlin_mathfrak_digit:n { 2 }}
    {3}{\__zlin_mathfrak_digit:n { 3 }}
    {4}{\__zlin_mathfrak_digit:n { 4 }}
    {5}{\__zlin_mathfrak_digit:n { 5 }}
    {6}{\__zlin_mathfrak_digit:n { 6 }}
    {7}{\__zlin_mathfrak_digit:n { 7 }}
    {8}{\__zlin_mathfrak_digit:n { 8 }}
    {9}{\__zlin_mathfrak_digit:n { 9 }}
   }
   { \TXmathfrak{#1} }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__zlin_mathfrak_digit:n
 {
  \text{\usefont{U}{euf}{b}{n}#1}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\{f_\rho^{\mathfrak{0}}, f_\rho^{\mathfrak{1}}, \cdots, f_\rho^{\mathfrak{K}} \}$

$\forall{\mathfrak{k}}\in\{\mathfrak{0},\cdots, \mathfrak{K}\}$. 

$\mathfrak{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}$

$\mathfrak{0123456789}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, use the AMS Euler Fraktur:

```
\documentclass{sokendai_thesis} % https://github.com/koikezlemma/phd_thesis_template/blob/master/sokendai_thesis.cls

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathfrak}{U}{euf}{m}{n}

\begin{document}

$\{f_\rho^{\mathfrak{0}}, f_\rho^{\mathfrak{1}}, \cdots, f_\rho^{\mathfrak{K}} \}$

$\forall{\mathfrak{k}}\in\{\mathfrak{0},\cdots, \mathfrak{K}\}$. 

$\mathfrak{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz}$

$\mathfrak{0123456789}$

\end{document}
```

[image]