# Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 5--5

Tags: graphics, overleaf, subfig

I'm trying to do a front page template in overleaf and got this error : Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 5--5

The figure I tried to use are not at the right place :

What it's supposed to looks like :

[image]

What it's really looking like:

[image]

Here is the code I use :

```
\begin{titlepage}
    \newgeometry{hmargin=2.5cm,vmargin=2cm}
        \begin{figure}
            \centering
            \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
                 \centering
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{logo_UCL.png}
             \end{subfigure}
             \hfill
            \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{logo_ELIE.jpg}
             \end{subfigure}
        \end{figure}
    
        \vspace*{\stretch{0.5}}
    
        \begin{center}
            \makeatletter 


            \textsc{Materials and methods}\\
            \vspace*{\stretch{0.1}}
            \textsc{First version}
    
            \vspace*{\stretch{0.5}}
            \LARGE
            \textbf{\@title}
    
            \vspace*{\stretch{1}}
            \normalsize
            \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} r}
                \textbf{Supervisor} & \textbf{Student} \\
                \supervisor       & \@author           \\
                \\
                \textbf{Cosupervisor} \\
                \assistantsupervisor \\
            \end{tabular*}
    
            \vspace*{\stretch{2}}
            \textsc{Academic year : 2023-2024} \\
            \vspace*{\stretch{0.1}}
        
            \makeatother
        \end{center}
    \restoregeometry
\end{titlepage}
```

And how I used it :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{extreport}

\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[
    a4paper,
    top=2cm,bottom=2cm,
    outer=2cm,inner=3cm,
    includeheadfoot
]{geometry}     
\usepackage[a-1a]{pdfx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\bibliography{Lac Tanganyika}

\title{Identification of water quality spatiotemporal variability on estuarine areas of Lake Tanganyika}
\author{Aurélien Lengrand}
\date{GG/MM/AAAA}
\newcommand{\supervisor}{Vanclooster Marnik}
\newcommand{\assistantsupervisor}{Alonso Alice}

\begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    \pagestyle{empty}

    \input{title_page}
    \cleardoublepage

    \section{Schéma global}
    \section{Chlorophyll-A}
        This map \cite{bergamino_spatio-temporal_2010}
    \section{Remote sensing}
    \section{OCX equation}
    \printbibliography[]
\end{document}
```

Here is a link to my overleaf document :

https://www.overleaf.com/6898685677zgvcznvbhscm#afa28c

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) If I add a minimal document around your code, add the packages I think you are loading, and replace the figures by some I actually have, everything works nicely. Whatever is going on is due to code you are not showing. Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) which reproduces the issue, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. In this way we can copy-paste the code and look at the problem without resorting to wild guesses about what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, I edited my question with the code I used to compile this page

Comment: https://www.overleaf.com/6898685677zgvcznvbhscm#afa28c

Comment: see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334246/what-does-the-phrase-underfull-hbox-badness-10000-in-paragraph-actually-mea/334249#334249

Comment: please provide an example here that shows the problem, do not use external links

Comment: The code you have here has many errors related to the subfigure environments.

Comment: you should not be using figure or subfigure in a titlepage these are not floating inserts, just use `\includegraphics`.