# Random Indentation In my code

Tags: errors, indentation, multicol

Here is my COde:

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{article}

\usepackage[margin = 0.25in, letterpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{multicol}


\begin{document}
\begin{framed}
    \section[short]{Functions and Algebra}
    \textbf{POLYNOMIALS}\\
    For \(p(x)~|~ n~is~the~degree~of~p(x);\)\\
    \(p(x) = a_{0}x^0 + a_{1}x + a_{2}x^2 ... a_{n}a^n \)\\
    With \(p(x)\) having \(n\) number of \(zeros(z), complex ~ or ~ real\), can be factored, \\
    \(p(x)=(x-z_{1})(x-z_{2})...(x-z_{n})\)
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{framed}
            \begin{center}
                Common Factoring Formulae: \\
                \(a^2 - b^2 = (a+b)(a-b)\)\\
                \(a^3 \pm b^3 = (a-b)(a^2 + b^2 \mp ab)\)
            \end{center}
        \end{framed}
        \columnbreak
        \begin{framed}
            \begin{center}
                Common Expanding Formulae: \\
                \((a \pm b)^2 = a^2 \pm 2ab +b^2\)\\
                \((a \pm b)^3 = a^3 \pm 3a^2b + 3ab^2 + b^2\)
            \end{center}
        \end{framed}
    \end{multicols}
    \textbf{FUNCTIONS}\\
    Reflection of a function over the \(y-axis\) of \(f(x)\) is \(f(-x)\)\\
    Reflection of a function over the \(x-axis\) of \(f(x)\) is \(-f(x)\)\\
    Trasformation of \(f(x) \rightarrow af[b(x-h)]+k\)\\


    \section[short]{Logarithms}
    Defined as \(a^b = x \longleftrightarrow \log_{a}x = b \)\\
    Principle Identities;\\
    \(a^{\log_{a}x} = x\) ~~
    \(\log_{a}1=0\) ~~
    \(\log_{a}a=1\) ~~
    \(\log_{\frac{1}{a}}a = -1\)
\end{framed}
\end{document}
```

There seems to be a random indentation in line 37; `\textbf{FUNCTIONS}\\`

The error code is `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000)LaTeX`

I searched for the error and fixed previous issues of this same error code, but I can't seem to get this exact one fixed. Here is what My output looks like. I'll highlight the random indentation:
[image: Here is what My output looks like. I'll highlight the random indentation:]

Please help me, I am a beginner LaTeX programmer. Sorry if this question was asked already.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334246/what-does-the-phrase-underfull-hbox-badness-10000-in-paragraph-actually-mea/334249#334249

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Underfull \hbox (badness 10000)` is because you have misplaced `\\`  at the end of a paragraph, delete all of those.

The red arrow is not a "random indent" it is a normal start of paragraph indent, you should use a section heading such as

```
\subsection*{FUNCTIONS}
```

not `\textbf`

POLOYNOMIALS should also be `\subsection*` the indent is suppressed in that case as it is the first paragraph after the `\section{Functions and Algebra}` heading.

Comment: So sorry for my stupid mistakes, If I don't put the \\ in my code, I won't have the new line. Is there any way for me to do that without \\? 


I'm a bare beginner, so do you have any websites that I can refer to for code commands? Thanks, A LOT. I will make sure to not make this mistake again

Comment: @grade12boi Simple rule: ***don't*** use ``\\`` to end lines in normal text. A paragraph is ended by leaving a blank line in the input file.

Comment: if you marked it as a section heading you would get a newline without `\\ ` and for ending normal paragraphs just use a blank line in the source. You should almost never have `\\ ` except to mark the ends of table rows. @grade12boi