# How to use file content as a numeric value for a length?

Tags: input, lengths

I'm trying to read the content from a file and then use it in the formula:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\newcommand\x{\input{size.txt}}
\setlength\parskip{1pt * \x}
\begin{document}
Hello, world!
\end{document}
```

I'm getting:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
                   \let
l.4 \setlength\parskip{1pt * \x}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: I don't suppose you have control over how the file is created?  It's much simpler to have size.tex say `\setlength\parskip{6pt}` and then `\input{size}`.

Comment: I truly need the size to be in `size.txt` file, as a positive integer

Comment: Follow-up question: [How to \read inside a command and return the result?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/628870/4301).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\read` rather than `\input`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newread\foo
\openin\foo=size.txt
\read\foo to \x

\setlength\parskip{\x pt}
\begin{document}
Hello, world!

a new paragraph
\end{document}
```

where `size.txt` is

```
20
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `catchfile`.

```
%%% filecontents is used just to make the example self-contained
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.txt}
20
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{catchfile}
\usepackage{calc}

%%%
% define \x to be the contents of the file
\CatchFileDef{\x}{\jobname.txt}{}

% now use it
\setlength\parskip{1pt * \x}
%%%

\begin{document}

Hello, world! \the\parskip

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can then use `\x` wherever and whenever you need it. I'd use a more descriptive name, though.

For a single use, I'd not leave around a definition of `\x`; in this case you can replace the code in the `%%%` pair with

```
%%%
\begingroup\CatchFileDef{\x}{\jobname.txt}{}
\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\setlength\parskip{1pt * \x}}\x
%%%
```

Here's a more general version that allows you to perform various actions with the content of a file. In the second argument to `\usefile` you use `#1` to refer to the file contents.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.txt}
20
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\usefile}{mm}
 {% #1 = file name, #2 = action to perform
  \yegor_usefile:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__yegor_usefile_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \yegor_usefile:nn
 {
  \cs_set_protected:Nn \__yegor_usefile_aux:n { #2 }
  \file_get:nnN { #1 } { } \l__yegor_usefile_tl
  \__yegor_usefile_aux:V \l__yegor_usefile_tl
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__yegor_usefile_aux:n {}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__yegor_usefile_aux:n { V }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\usefile{\jobname.txt}{\setlength{\parskip}{1pt * #1}}

\begin{document}

Hello, world! \the\parskip

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that your newcommand will expand and simply include the content of size.tex (in my case). It does no numerical conversion, and there seem to be no obvious way to do it.

May be if you have a look into the TEX-manual, there might be a way to get the number of bytes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\newcommand\x{\input{size}}
%\setlength\parskip{1pt * \x}
\begin{document}
Hello, world!

\x{}
\end{document}
```

Kindly guess the content of size.tex ;-)

[image]

**P.S.**: You may succeed with package `stringstrings`, see `stringlength` in  https://mirror.marwan.ma/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/stringstrings/stringstrings.pdf

Comment: Still wondering, what the use cases are for your idea ...

Comment: I may be misinterpreting you or OP, but I think size.txt has a number for its content, and OP isn't trying to get the size of the file.

Comment: the idea is size.txt is a one line file with the text (say) 20  which should cause a 20pt paragraph separation. This does not answer the question.

Comment: Right ... so the question could at least be understood this way ...

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the `-shell-escape` option to execute a command to obtain the desired value. In the MWE below, the file `MySize.txt` had the value of 30 and this value was used to set `\parskip`:

[image]

#### References:

- [Specify file name shell access via \@@input](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102365/4301)
- [How to use the parskip package? (space in between paragraphs)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40429/4301)

#### Code:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{MySize.txt}
30
\end{filecontents*}%

\documentclass{article}

%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102365/specify-file-name-shell-access-via-input
\makeatletter
\newcommand\GetShellOutput[1]{%
    %% #1 = file name
  \begingroup\endlinechar=\m@ne\everyeof{\noexpand}%
  \edef\TempResult{\endgroup
    \def\noexpand\ShellOutput{%
      \@@input|"cat #1" }}%
  \TempResult}
\makeatother

\newcommand\SetValueFromFile[2]{%
    %% #1 = macro to set
    %% #2 = file to read (which contains an integer)
    \GetShellOutput{#2}%
    \def#1{\ShellOutput}%
}%

\SetValueFromFile{\GivenInteger}{MySize.txt}
\setlength\parskip{\GivenInteger pt}


\begin{document}
Hello, world!

Hello again.
\end{document}
```