# How to \read inside a command and return the result?

Tags: input, lengths, calc

As a followup of [How to use file content as a numeric value for a length?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/628798/how-to-use-file-content-as-a-numeric-value-for-a-length), I'm trying to do this (I really need to read the `data.txt` file inside this new command and use the value later, when the command is called):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\x{
  \newread\foo
  \openin\foo=data.txt
  \read\foo to \temp
  \temp
}
\setlength\parskip{1pt * \x}
\end{document}
```

I'm getting:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
                   \global
l.35 \setlength\parskip{1pt * \x}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: No, you can't do like that. But what would be the reason to?

Comment: why not read in the value once and then use that after? or just `\input`

Comment: @plante can you show me how, please? I need to have `\x` in the end, which I can use in calculations of lengths.

Comment: This seems like a follow-up to [How to use file content as a numeric value for a length?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/628798/4301). Please do include such information in the question as that will help those trying to help you.

Comment: What's wrong with the `\CatchFileDef` method I suggested? If you plan to use `\x` several times, it allows to read the file just once. Of course, in this case, I'd not call the value `\x`, but use a more descriptive name.

Comment: @egreg could you please post a working example as an answer? I will accept it.

Comment: @yegor256 Isn't there in the answer to you previous question?

Comment: the reason for setting the read to save to \x is so that \x can be used in an expansion.

Comment: you only need to read the file once, which you can do in the preamble, then use `\x` as often as you want, why do you need to read the same file multiple times???

Comment: @DavidCarlisle this is just an example. My real case is much more complex and I do need to read the file many times (it's being generated by an external command).

Comment: @egreg please, post it here, to keep the consistency of Q&A

Comment: still whenever you run the external command you can re read the file

Answer (score 2):

You can do this, but it requires LuaTeX. There you can use \beginlocalcontrol/\endlocalcontrol to define a block of code which gets fully executed (including opening file) during TeX's expansion stage:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}

% First define \beginlocalcontrol based on tex.runtoks
\newluafunction\beginlocalcontrol
\directlua{lua.get_functions_table()[\the\allocationnumber] = function() return tex.runtoks(token.get_next) end}
\luadef\beginlocalcontrol\allocationnumber
\begin{document}
\newcommand\x{%
  \beginlocalcontrol % This block gets executed during expansion
    \begingroup % Let's keep our definitions local to avoid confusion macros which might not expect definitions to change during expansion
    \newread\foo
    \openin\foo=data.txt
    \read\foo to \temp
    \closein\foo
    \expandafter\endgroup % The two \expandafter's ensure that the final \temp gets the value from inside of the \endgroup and \endlocalcontrol blocks.
  \expandafter\endlocalcontrol
  \temp
}
\setlength\parskip{1pt * \x}
\end{document}
```

I would recommend though to move at least the `\newread \foo` outside of the command, otherwise you waste one input file every time the macro gets expanded.

Comment: The `\newread` should go outside the definition of `\x`, I believe.

Comment: It's inside to demonstrate that it's possible, but I agree that for all practical purposes it's better to keep it outside.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this question happens to be solvable:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter

\setlength\parskip{\@@input{b.tex}pt}
\typeout{\the\parskip}

\setlength\parskip{\dimexpr 1pt*\@@input{b.tex}\relax}
\typeout{\the\parskip}

\makeatother

\end{document}
```

Assuming `b.tex` contains `123`, both will print out `123.0pt`.

Comment: p/s: if some experienced users gives clunky workarounds in answers, chances are they actually want to say "your original request is unsolvable"... which given the quirks of TeX is more likely than not.

Comment: and `\@@input` has some quirks that makes it not work inside an edef, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/516031/why-is-everyeof-noexpand-needed-to-avoid-file-ended-while-scanning-definitio.

Answer (score 0):

`\read` is not expandable but is an assignment-command itself.
Thus it cannot be carried out in the course of carrying out another assignment-command like `\setlength`.
As you intend to define a scratch-macro `\x` you can do s.th. like this:

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}{mydata.txt}
8
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\newread\foo

\begin{document}
\immediate\openin\foo=mydata.txt
\immediate\read\foo to \x
\immediate\closein\foo
%\setlength\parskip{1pt * \x}
\setlength\parskip{\x pt}
\showthe\parskip
\end{document}
```

`\@@input` is LaTeX 2ε's copy of the expandable TeX-primitive `\input`.
`\input`/`\@@input` cannot be carried out in the course of directly obtaining a set of tokens that is to form a macro argument because in any case the end of the file will be encountered which is treated like an `\outer` token.
But you can arrange things in a way where they are not processed as macro arguments:

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}{mydata.txt}
8
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\parskip=\csname @@input\endcsname mydata.txt pt %
%\parskip=\dimexpr1pt*(\csname @@input\endcsname mydata.txt )\relax
\showthe\parskip
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to do an assignment, expandability is not a factor.

The simplest method is to define a suitable command, say

```
\setlengthfromfile{<length>}{<file>}{<expression>}
```

where `<length>` is the register you want to set, `<file>` is the file you want to read a value from and `<expression>` contains `#1` to denote the file contents, so your case would be

```
\setlengthfromfile{\parskip}{data.txt}{1pt * #1}
```

Code with examples:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.dat}
20
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\setlengthfromfile}{mmm}
 {% #1 = length parameter
  % #2 = file name
  % #3 = expression
  \yegor_setlengthfromfile:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \__yegor_setlengthfromfile_aux:n { } % initialize
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__yegor_setlengthfromfile_aux:n { V }

\tl_new:N \l__yegor_setlengthfromfile_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \yegor_setlengthfromfile:nnn
 {
  \file_get:nnN { #2 } { } \l__yegor_setlengthfromfile_tl
  \cs_set:Nn \__yegor_setlengthfromfile_aux:n { #3 }
  \skip_set:Nn #1 { \__yegor_setlengthfromfile_aux:V \l__yegor_setlengthfromfile_tl }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\setlengthfromfile{\parskip}{\jobname.dat}{1pt * #1}
\showthe\parskip

\setlengthfromfile{\parskip}{\jobname.dat}{1pt * #1-12pt}
\showthe\parskip

\setlengthfromfile{\parskip}{\jobname.dat}{#1\parskip}
\showthe\parskip

\setlengthfromfile{\parskip}{\jobname.dat}{#1pt plus 0.1pt}
\showthe\parskip

\stop
```

The console will show

```
(./yegordim.dat
)
> 20.0pt.
l.31 \showthe\parskip

?
(./yegordim.dat)
> 8.0pt.
l.34 \showthe\parskip

?
(./yegordim.dat)
> 160.0pt.
l.37 \showthe\parskip

?
(./yegordim.dat)
> 20.0pt plus 0.1pt.
l.40 \showthe\parskip
```

In the third example we reused the previous value of `\parskip`.