# What is \newluafunction? How can I use it?

Tags: luatex

As in the title. I found from [some answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/628874/250119) that there seems to be a macro `\newluafunction` in LaTeX.

However, documentation seems quite sparse...

[image: Screenshot from source2e.pdf]

- What's a "named `\luafunction`"? Is it expandable/unexpandable/global etc.?
- What does it mean to define one?
- How can I use the macro to define a function, then call the function?

Comment: Also special case of [macros - Where do I find out how a command/environment is defined? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4327/where-do-i-find-out-how-a-command-environment-is-defined/) but source2e seems not particularly useful on this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

A wrapper allocating a number to use with `\luafunction` and `\luadef`, but possibly not that useful compared to `\newluacmd` or its Lua equivalent, `luatexbase.new_luafunction`.

A csname defined via `\luadef` directly accesses a luatex Lua table of functions, so it is equivalent to using `\directlua` with a Lua function call, except that it saves an expansion of a macro name, and it saves expanding the argument of `\directua` as TeX tokens and passing to Lua to be evaluated each time. So `\qqq` below is `\directlua{qqq()}` but quicker.

```
\documentclass{article}

\directlua{
qqqn=0
function qqq ()
qqqn=qqqn+1
tex.print(qqqn)
end
}
\newluafunction\qqqn

\directlua {
local t = lua.get_functions_table()
t[\the\qqqn] = qqq
}

\luadef\qqq\qqqn

\begin{document}

A: \qqq

B: \qqq

\end{document}
```

In practice, it would have been better to simply use the size of the `lua.get_functions_table()` table, rather than a TeX-allocated number, but it seemed a good idea at the time.

See also `\newluacmd` which was added later which allocates numbers from the same sequence but avoids the need for an extra explicit call to `\luadef`

```
\documentclass{article}

\directlua{
qqqn=0
function qqq ()
qqqn=qqqn+1
tex.print(qqqn)
end
}
\newluacmd\qqq

\directlua {
local t = lua.get_functions_table()
t[\number\allocationnumber] = qqq
}

\begin{document}

A: \qqq

B: \qqq

\end{document}
```

`luatexbase` makes the same allocation available from Lua as `luatexbase.new_luafunction` which saves passing numbers back and forth between TeX and Lua. This defines `\qqq` to directly refer to the Lua function with all allocation and definition being done in Lua.

```
\documentclass{article}

\directlua{
qqqn=0
function qqq ()
qqqn=qqqn+1
tex.print(qqqn)
end

local funid= luatexbase.new_luafunction()

lua.get_functions_table()[funid]=qqq
token.set_lua('qqq',funid)
}

\begin{document}

A: \qqq

B: \qqq

\end{document}
```