# How to change the indentation of a quote environment?

Tags: quoting

I am using a `\begin{quote}` ... `\end{quote}` environment. Is it possible to change the indentation of the quote? Or do I need another package?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage[
  expansion = false ,
  tracking = smallcaps ,
  letterspace = 40 ,
]{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Acknowledgments}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{quote}
{\small This operation is somewhat like the periscope of a submarine. All you see is the three of us, but beneath the surface are thousands and thousands of others.}
\end{quote}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

The quotation is from astronaut Michael Collins, by the way.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel: you have the `quoting` package.

Comment: See [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2396/how-can-i-change-the-indentation-in-quote-and-quotation-environments-and-command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2396/110998)

Comment: you also need to remove the `{}` around `{\small....}` as it is you are getting small text on a normal (over large) baseline.